# Obsolete questions/answers

Tags: discussion

What is the policy on questions that are obsolete (e.g. almost no one uses that technology anymore) or whose answers are obsolete (e.g. they address an old version of JavaScript)? This is purely a question about policy, not on what should or should not happen.

Comment: Answers that are obsolete remain. If something is obsolete, add a comment as to why it's obsolete, and/or add a new updated answer.

Comment: What if I don't know the answer?

Comment: Likewise, questions that are obsolete should remain. How do ***you*** know that someone out there isn't still using that "obsolete" technology, and would find the question (and its answers) useful?

Comment: People use older versions of languages all the time.  That doesn't make the information useless.  And SO is there to cover the long tail of questions, so having a smaller target audience for a question isn't a problem.

Comment: Note that sometimes people do still have to use obsolete technology. Less than a year ago, I had to come to SO in search of how to fix something for somebody that was still using mssql 2000. The fix would have been much simpler on even sql 2005, but nope, 2000 or nothing.

Comment: @TrentonMaki If you don't know the answer to a question you do the same thing you always do for any question.  You either figure out the answer and then answer it, or you leave the question alone.  A question being unanswerable, as opposed to you just not knowing the answer, is the reason to do something different (namely close it).

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068253/edsac-17bit-and-35bit-integers) is the record holder.  It was turned off in 1958.

Comment: lol, thanks for that question. I can't believe it has an answer.

Comment: @HansPassant Upvoted this question because it led to your comment being posted. That's hilarious.

Comment: Many questions don't explicitly state the version of a technology they apply to (e.g., see [my comment on this use of a library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134799/creating-a-signed-s3-url-with-javascript/8134993#comment38313502_8134993)). Some questions look broad but apply only to a very old version (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048440/webkittransform-bug-in-safari-am-i-going-mad/8060165#8060165). Seeing these as search results or Related links is rarely useful. Being able to mark them prominently with an Obsolete tag that would show up in the title would be helpful.

Comment: @cupcake - but sometimes one is forced to newer technology. I've just been looking at a Google Analytics question from 2010. Google is a hosted service. You can not use the 2010 version any more. The question is no longer meaningful, the answers obsoleted by changes in currently available implementations. What should be done about this aged, irrelevant question? I'd prefer to see questions and answers that are now irreproducible, reduced in ranking. Some of these ancient questions are chart toppers - and completely useless, *now*.

Comment: @JezC ask a new question and link to the old one?

Comment: @cupcake - but the problem posed by the question, is resolved by using newer software, with no access to the old software. You simply can't ask that question, now. It's just a non-issue, now. I wouldn't want to link to it, as it would be, from a current perspective, insane. It'd be like answering an ancient mammal's question about avoiding T rex. We just don't have that problem any more. We've evolved beyond it. The problem is a non-issue, now, and ever after.

Comment: @JezC add a comment to the question explaining that the technology is completely obsoleted? Ask a new Meta question about the specific question, if you feel that it deserves special attention.

Comment: @cupcake - but how to stop these questions, that have no currently useful function, from topping listings of GA questions, and turning in Google search results? SE is very good at ranking on Google, but the answers to obsolete questions are to no-one's benefit. Google itself can't tell that the answer to a 2010 question, that disappeared as a problem in 2012, is not relevant now. I ask, because that's how I reached a highly ranked, highly viewed answer that is useless.

Comment: @mikaraento suggested an obsolete tag which might help. Another thing that could work is adding version numbers (either in comments, tags, or something else).

Comment: A newer development is *[Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project)* (2021).