# Survey questions for outdated answers

Tags: discussion, product-discovery, answers, answer-quality, announcement

**Update:** Thank you MSO for the responses. We've incorporated your feedback into the proposed questions and the site satisfaction survey is now live for March 2021.

---

We are kicking off a project to begin tackling the issue of outdated answers on Stack Overflow. [See this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project) for details on the initiative and our approach.

We plan to add a few questions to our Site Satisfaction survey that is shown to a random sample of Stack Overflow users each month.

Our goal is to gain a better understanding of what types of answers are considered outdated. Here are the proposed questions:

> 1. What types of outdated answers have you seen on Stack Overflow? (Select all that apply)
>
>    1. Answers that have become obsolete as new versions of frameworks became available.
>    2. Answers that still work, but there is a newer, better way to achieve the same end.
>    3. Answers that may have never been the best, but were accepted by the question asker.
>    4. Answers that now pose security risks or provide code that no longer works.
>    5. Answers that still hold value to a subset of developers who use legacy technology, but aren't valuable to developers on newer
>       technologies.
>    6. Other ________
> 2. Which factors help you determine that an answer is outdated? (Select all that apply)
>
>    1. Timestamps (e.g., answered, edited, etc.)
>    2. Downvote count
>    3. Comments
>    4. Sorting answers (e.g., active, oldest, votes)
>    5. Trying out the code
>    6. Other _________
> 3. What do you currently do when you encounter an outdated answer?

Have we covered all of the common use cases?
If you have any suggestions for improving the survey questions, please add them as answers below.

**Feedback requested by Wed, Feb 24.**

Answer (score 73):

4. What would you like to see happen to outdated, *accepted* answers?

   1. Removal of the green tick *by the system*.
   2. Removal of the green tick *by staff or moderators (or tag experts).*
   3. Moving the green tick to a better answer (as chosen by tag experts).
   4. …

Comment: 4. Reordering of the answers such that the accepted answer is treated as any other answer.

Comment: Perhaps a slight change to 3. Tag experts could also be allowed to remove the green tick to indicate that all of the answers are outdated.

Comment: @cigien Indeed. For *abandoned* accepted answers (where questioner's account is long-time inactive or deleted), I think tag experts would *have* to be involved in deciding on whether an answer is outdated.

Comment: Right. I meant the phrasing in 3. suggests that tag experts should only be able to *move* the green tick to another answer, as opposed to *removing* it entirely from a particular post.

Comment: @IanCampbell I understand your concern, but that's a discussion ongoing elsewhere.

Comment: @IanCampbell OK - you mean such reordering *only* for *outdated* accepted answers?

Comment: Yes, exactly. "Reordering of answers such that *outdated* accepted answers are treated as any other answer" might be better.

Comment: I sympathize, but I think the green tick should be kept to mean "the answer of most use to the person asking the question at the time the question was asked (or when an answer was accepted)". At least, the information in the green tick should be kept. Maybe instead of removing the green tick, allowing a different check mark to indicate "Chosen by the community as preferable to the accepted answer". Or changing the current green tick to perhaps an orange tick indicating this was (is!) the OP's selection, and bestowing the green tick on another answer. This changes the meaning of the green tick.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But then we'd need a committee to decide what colour to change the green tick to. :)

Comment: Oh, there'll be committees (or extensive discussions) all over the place. Using an orange checkmark would indicate some warning status — this was what the OP chose, but the community considers there are solid reasons to recommend an alternative answer since the question was asked. Maybe a blue checkmark for the community preferred answer (and it gets pinned to the top like the green does now), and the orange checkmark for the demoted answer (which might or might not be kept as the second entry after the new blue entry). Just thinking out loud. Orange connotes 'warning'; blue is more neutral.

Comment: Survey question 5: If the color of the checkmark is to be changed for outdated answers, what color do you suggest? 1: Orange, 2: Hot Pink, 3: Rainbow

Comment: Can we include a colour-picker control in the survey's UI?

Comment: Another question: does the newly designated accepted answer earn the 'accept' bonus?  Corollary: does the newly demoted, previously accepted answer lose the 'accept' bonus.  I think the answer to both should be "No". I'm more firmly of the opinion that the demoted answer should not lose the accept bonus since it is still the answer accepted by the OP.  Whether the now preferred answer should gain an accept bonus is more debatable, but "No" is the simplest answer to implement.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree with your last comment. "No" x 2 is what I would also suggest.

Comment: And should there be badges for providing the 'newly accepted' answer — bronze for one such, silver for 10, gold for 25?  Should there be badges for providing 'newly demoted answer' — again, maybe bronze for 1, silver for 10, gold for 25?  Should the gold be awarded per 25 qualifying answers?  All suggested thresholds are fungible to values deemed more suitable.

Comment: While I like your proposed question, I don't know whether it is suited for the given survey. As I understand it, they first want to find out what we _consider_ an outdated answer, and what we do about it _right now_. I guess that asking what we _want_ to be done about it is subject to a later survey.

Comment: I agree with this as a question, and I upvoted it, but I really don't think that asking about it adds value.  Their own research shows that we've had extensive conversation about this already, and they should probably just experiment to see what the outcome is.  No reason to delay this, in my opinion.

Comment: I have never once in my life seen an accepted answer with fewer votes than another answer and thought to myself, "I'm glad that green check mark elevated this answer above the more popular one."  Quite the opposite, in fact.

Comment: I like this idea, but I'd like it to go beyond just the check mark. What about highly upvoted outdated answers that aren't accepted? I think it would be a good idea to aesthetically change the way outdated answers are shown, like shade them brown or yellow to indicate age. Note that outdated != old, I think only an expert can make this decision, and votes aren't super helpful either, since it's possible that a low activity question might have +5/-2, and the +5 came from 2008-2013 but the -2 came due to a serious problem that was revealed later.

Comment: If we had a different color checkmark/different icon, it could be useful for historical reasons. Sometimes the answer deprecated by language or library release on a later version could still be used by someone who is unable to upgrade their system (I consulted a company still on PHP 5.X) so someway of indicating "Correct for version", with a tooltip with a note saying "Deprecate this checkmark", and a user permission (or user score on a tag) to vote. Adding a moderation queue for tag-experts to review the votes, maybe?

Comment: @AdrianMole the most [thought provoking post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261825) I've seen on this.

Comment: I think this answer is really bad and off-topic. It misrepresents the historical posts on changing the check mark that are much more complex and varied than just 3 simplistic options. This post also derails the scope of the initial survey questions and distracts from them.

Comment: Don't you think this can be abused? If the tag expert already has an answer under the question and it was not marked as correct, maybe they removed the green check and added it to their answer?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes I also thought about that, if you read the previous discussions on this over the years the proposed solutions were all about sorting only rarely did someone mention removing the check mark because that would inevitably raise the problems of potential abuse.

Comment: @PeterHaddad I see the checkmark changing/removal process as a community effort - 3 gold badge "tag experts" would need to vote in favor of it. Maybe even 5, I dunno.

Comment: @MattDMo well, too many gold badge holders can make the whole point moot. If my query is correct, only about a quarter of the tags which have at least one gold badge have 5 of them. Stats are much better for 2 badges, but for consistency with other site features 3 SME's seem just about right

Comment: @MattDMo NO. I don't think it would work out - see [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405460).

Comment: Please don't remove the green check mark. Not all accepted answers are outdated & many are still useful. I have seen instances where the accepted answer is a heavily downvoted answer but it helps me with my problems.

Comment: @bad_coder I think that situation is rather extreme - I've never come across anyone else like that besides Wiktor, but there are a lot of tags I don't frequent, so that may just be me. But, it's partially for reasons like this that I suggested needing the involvement or 3 or even 5 gold badge holders, so it truly is a community consensus. However, reading other arguments here, I don't necessarily think that removing/altering check marks is the best solution.

Comment: @MattDMo it took me some time to realize: This top voted post **has nothing to do with *"outdated"*** and everything to do with removing the green check mark (at "who knows whose discretion"). That's the only aim of this post to justify that ulterior aim (notice it bundles "incorrect" with "outdated").

Comment: @bad_coder What? My proposed question is *only* concerned with outdated answers. The discussion, in the comments, may have drifted towards more general attitudes about accepted answers and the pros and cons of the green tick, but that is secondary. In fact, I'm very much in favour of the idea(s) raised by Jonathan Leffler: keep the tick (and reputation points) for accepted answers but modify it (colour change) to indicate that it is no longer appropriate - for whatever reason.

Comment: @AdrianMole it took me a long time of rereading your post several times. Even if that wasn't your original intention look at it very carefully and notice what the post actually does convey textually. (Because it has an emphasis, in 2 words "remove" + "expert". And it wanders from "outdated" to "incorrect".)

Comment: @bad_coder Maybe you're hallucinating? There is ***no occurrence*** of the word, "incorrect," in my post.

Comment: Also bear in mind that the final, `4. ...` was there (from the get-go) to allow the possibility of other options (such as "Do nothing about the Green Tick"). It's not for me to *completely* design the question and all possible answers: I just offered a suggestion (as we were encouraged to do by Lisa's question).

Comment: @AdrianMole I don't think so, because you finish saying "to a better answer" (and even given the context you can consider anything that is incorrect as outdated.) That's what it says. Because if you put the process of removal into place, there's really nothing to distinguish outdated from incorrect (that is what part of the debate on the other thread about this is saying, but the historical posts only rarely would go in that direction).

Comment: Someone who has earned the _"foo-bar-quux"_ gold tag badge years ago doesn't necessarily mean they are a modern day expert in _"foo-bar-quux"_. Their skills/knowledge of _"foo-bar-quux"_ may have become _outdated_. So what factors determine that someone is a _"tag expert"_ in _"foo-bar-quux"_ and therefore makes them suitable to reassign the green tick?

Comment: @RobC Of course. But, if you are going to recruit experts to help in this task, then you have to have *some* method of selecting those experts. Gold badges may not be perfect, but they're likely the best indicator we have.

Comment: @AdrianMole - Oh, I hadn't realized recruiting experts was on the agenda for this. Yes gold tags is an indicator, however that alone doesn't IMO qualify as being a modern day SME.

Comment: @RobC I don't know what's on or off the agenda; I, like you, am just a mere mortal. The agenda will be set by the staff handling the matter. But your comment is a good one: maybe gold tag badges *plus* some more subtle selection criteria?

Comment: It the question is product related (framework, software) than the green check mark could very well be related to the product up to a certain version and after that no longer. The green check mark is a moment in time and signals: in this point of the time the answer correct (but no longer so). The problem with the check mark it does not reflect this chronology of the topic.

Comment: The success of stackoverflow has been the democratic nature of its voting system. The best answers have risen to the top. Rather than involving tag-experts or staff, or moderators, let everyone decide if the answer is outdated by vote, the same way we decide if an answer is useful.

Answer (score 57):

One of the factors that would influence me when determining whether an answer is outdated is:

- Subject matter expertise

I'd expect that any determination of an answer being outdated would primarily be made by subject matter experts (plural), and the best surrogate for identifying SMEs on SO is probably 'gold tag badge' in at least one of the tags for the question.

Age alone is not a determining factor, and neither are downvotes (or upvotes); however, both can be indicative.  Comments can be useful.  Sorting the answers is not usually needed in the areas where I work — there aren't usually so many answers that it is a problem.  I'd rarely use 'trying the code' as a way of determining that it is outdated, though I might test the code after I'd deduced it was outdated by other criteria.

Comment: Yep, in fact I would say the majority of the time I know an answer is outdated simply based on my knowledge of the subject.

Comment: It says "Which factors help you determine... Select all that apply". Maybe the intended meaning is, select nothing - you determined what you did without any help.

Comment: So one way to go about this might be to have "flag as outdated" and then a special user review queue for such posts, where you only get access to reviews when you have a gold badge in one of the used tags? I think that would be a sensible system, except for some oddball corner cases (I have a gold badge in "arrays" for example).

Comment: And conversely, there are obscure tags where nobody has gold. I am one of the top answerers in the [tag:procmail] tag across the network but at this rate it will be hundreds of years before I or anyone else captures a gold badge.

Comment: Gold tag badge = SME is too limiting. I suggest that total reputation is enough to determine competency at flagging and/or fixing outdated answers. I have 25+ years' experience in IT and software development. I don't know much about git, but recently started a project that uses it. At this point, I've spent enough time on SO looking at git questions and answers that I know an outdated answer when I see one. I would absolutely take the time to fix any I find if an SO process existed that allowed me to do so.

Comment: @cb4 the tag badges are not a very good measure of "experts" because one can put a lot of effort into curating a tag but that doesn't translate at all to a badge. If you mark 1000 questions as duplicates, that's probably a higher level of expertise than answering 1000 duplicate questions. But only one of these actions actually moves you towards a badge. Overall, a gold badge user is *more likely* to be more knowledgeable about a subject than a non-gold badge user but it's not a reliable metric by all means. Unfortunately, it's the best we currently have.

Comment: @VLAZ Understood and agree. My intent was aimed at avoiding the bottleneck of limited SMEs for curation. Perhaps a rep score > N and a brief test of understanding as is done for the review queues would be sufficient, with frequent reminders to skip curation if a reviewer does not feel completely comfortable addressing outdated content.

Comment: You mean actually having someone with knowledge of the subject matter making the call, instead of webbies guessing at it -- Wow, that might work, well!

Answer (score 49):

*Add this answer:*

- Which factors help you determine that an answer is outdated? (Select all that apply):

  - Bold text added at the top of the answer that says that it refers to such-and-such (outdated) version.

---

**Examples:**
[What is the difference between range and xrange functions in Python 2.X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/94935/967621)
[How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1267869/967621)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8220515/967621
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7950627/967621

Comment: I think this question is more about indirect factors.

Comment: @akuzminykh Re:factors - how more direct can you get than comments saying "this answer is outdated" (2.3)? :) Oftentimes, big shiny edited-in alerts are exactly what helps determine if the answer is outdated (besides, it is an interesting set of data to gather).

Comment: I mean I think the question "Which factors help you determine [...]" is more about indirect factors. The factor "Bold text added at the top [...]", something that clearly states an answer is outdated, is a direct factor. It's certain that it's an indicator for an outdated answer. There is really no benefit in gathering data about it.

Comment: @akuzminykh - I did not read that from the question. Anyways, I do not think we should artificially limit the breadth of collected data just on the direct/indirect distinction. What if we find out that post notices do not matter that much to people? This might lead to a prominent post notice feature or something along the lines.

Comment: @OlegValter You have good points there, I hope you're right. My assumption comes from what is written in the [main post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302/12323248). They've mentioned that they want to train a machine-learning model and the results of this survey will probably influence what inputs it has. But I think figuring out if the suggested factor should be an input is already clear: yes, of course. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: In addition to this, it must be mentioned that some systems are designed to run on older versions because they have been for the past 30+ years. While maintenance on such systems is still needed, the so-called outdated answers are very helpful for such systems. It should almost be a default policy that every answer contains a sentence: _This answer was designed for version X or earlier_

Answer (score 44):

> 2. Which factors help you determine that an answer is outdated?
>
>    2. Downvote count

I don't think I've ever seen an outdated answer getting downvoted. Do you have some data showing that it happens?

Personally, I don't downvote outdated answers.

1. It's not the right thing to do if the answer was valid when the question was asked.
2. It serves no purpose if the answer has a high number of upvotes. My downvote would be unnoticed and fail to help the reader determine that the answer is outdated.

On the contrary, a factor that helps determine if an answer is outdated is the upvote count on the newest answers. What I usually look at is if one or several recent answers (i.e. posted many years after the original answers) have an unusual high number of upvotes.

So maybe change 2.2 to **High upvote count on newest answers**.

Comment: I recieved a downvote today for [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9712592/371) which is nearly 9 years old and cannot possibly be relevant to the current situation. The answer below it has almost 3x as many upvotes and is slightly younger at only 7 years but is obviously providing more help (has zero downvotes).

Comment: Once you've reached 1000 rep, you can [view vote counts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user). Just because I'm curious, I often look at question and answer vote counts to see if something notable has happened in the past. Downvotes do accumulate over time, so don't be afraid to do it.

Comment: @MattDMo Vote counts by itself doesn't show if the downvotes are recent. You need to go in https://stackoverflow.com/posts/xxxxxx/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries and analyze the votes timeline. That feature is gatekeeped by a minimum number of reputation as you said, so it doesn't help the basic reader. Also, it's still quicker to look for the newest answers with high upvotes than checking the votes timeline of every answer.

Comment: @MattDMo "Downvotes do accumulate over time, so don't be afraid to do it." – I disagree  with downvoting answers that were correct when the question was asked. I guess it goes with [not removing the green tick on the accepted answer, even if outdated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405307/survey-questions-for-outdated-answers/405425?noredirect=1#comment825419_405309).

Comment: Outdated but valid answers can still be very valuable for people stuck on (very) old versions of things, another reason simply being outdated is an invalid rationale for a downvote.  That said, it would certainly help the answer if some text is present indicating what versions etc. are relevant, or if it is known to be superceded.

Comment: It's interesting... do you know who does tend to downvote bad answers? Anonymous users and users who don't have enough reputation to downvote and we do have that data. It might not be perfect but it's definitely possible to see trends - "did votes start out very positive, flatten out and are now more downward? Maybe we should investigate why..." It's a signal, at the least.

Comment: *It's not the right thing to do if the answer was valid when the question was asked* - what?  If you don't maintain your answers, expect them to get downvotes from me if they're anti-helpful for future readers, regardless of the situation when you wrote them.  If they still work but aren't the *best* way, I wouldn't downvote (even if it was newly posted), but I don't accept age as an excuse for insecure, subtly-buggy, or broken-with-current-versions answers even if other people liked them at the time.  (Of course, I might just edit version info into the answer if it works well with older vers)

Comment: @Catija Interesting. Users who do not lose own reputation will click on the button :) Maybe we should all log out and go hit that button going through that long list of Answers we wish we had enough reputation to hit :D

Answer (score 36):

In my experience what many times helps determine if an answer is outdated are **other answers that directly mention it**. For example, a newer answer states in its body: *"The other answer(s) is/are outdated because..."*

I think the second topic in the survey doesn't mention this important use case and should include:

> 2. Which factors help you determine that an answer is outdated? (Select all that apply)
>
>    (...)
>
>    5. Trying out the code
>    6. **Other answers refer to the outdated answer(s).**

This is not the same as *2.3. Comments*.

Comment: Or combine them to say **"Comments/other answers referring to the outdated answer(s)"**

Comment: @MattDMo keeping the options separate allows to differentiate. It gives better quantitative data.

Comment: That's true, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Or the question is [self-edited years later to say it's out of date](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86734/why-should-one-want-to-disable-compiler-warnings/87061#87061)

Comment: @Casey that would make a good answer on this thread by itself.

Comment: I'm surprised to see this :) I had almost lost faith that anyone would mention it. I find there's only two factors that determines if an Answer works. Comments and Trying out the code. When I find something isn't working, I comment. Votes are useless for this. There are highly upvoted Answers that do not work and never did and downvoted Answers that work just fine.

Answer (score 20):

> 1.1. Answers that have become obsolete as new versions of frameworks became available.

I suggest changing the phrasing along the lines of: "Answers that have been made obsolete by new versions of a framework, language or library."

> 1.4. Answers that **now pose security risks** or provide code that no longer works.

*Are* there answers that pose security risks now that didn't at the time they were written?

The vast majority of questions that involve security flaws are wrong when written and should be downvoted out of the gate. Not that they always *are*, but that's not a question of obsolescence. I don't know if we really have a problem with answers that have become less secure (or more obviously insecure) over time. If you want statistics on that, I suggest separating it from the much larger and extremely real problem of answers that contain code that no longer works at all.

That said, I'm not sure whether there's a difference between this and 1.1, if 1.2 is for answers that "still work" then 1.1 would seem to be implicitly about answers that *don't* still work (presumably: "as well as they originally did") which would subsume this category entirely.

> 1.6 Other

I can think of one other category: **Answers to obsolete questions**, where the question *itself* is based on an outdated premise. Perhaps these need to be dealt with in a different way.

Comment: I absolutely agree with changing "*frameworks*". I would't call Python 2 and Python 3 different frameworks at all, they're different versions of the *language*.

Comment: I agree with 1.1 but I'm unsure about 1.4... maybe its uncommon, but new risks may come to light after the fact. Also and probably more likely, awareness of security issues could grow over time.

Comment: I don't say we should not be concerned about new security risks obsoleting old questions (although I can't really think of any examples except SHA1 being broken, and that has been known to be unsafe since before SO existed) -- I just don't think we should lump those into the same category as "code that no longer works". Code that works, but has a security vulnerability is not the same as code that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I would also add product to that list, e.g. a newer version of mysql,

Comment: I might add "Operating System" to the list of things that can cause obsolescence.   I guess you could consider that a framework...the mother of all frameworks.  This, from my experience, is a common cause of an answer becoming outdated/wrong.

Answer (score 6):

(Numbers refer to [Adrian Mole's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405309/1657610) as I'm suggesting these additional questions in the same area)

4. What would you like to see happen to outdated, *accepted* answers?

   ⋮

   4. *Modification* of the green tick *by the system* to give it a standard "outdated" appearance.
   5. *Modification* of the green tick *by staff or moderators (or tag experts)* to give it a standard "outdated" appearance *and annotate it with a brief text giving the "outdated" criteria used*.

   ⋮

Comment: Change the tick from green, to yellow, to red. I'm sure there's a smart, statistical way to figure this out, but even arbitrary numbers would help. Something like 0-3 years, 4-6 years, and 7+ years respectively.

Comment: Yes, perhaps combined with some kind of clever strike-through, so as to make it absolutely clear it is an "ex-tick".

Comment: This suggestion is off-topic, the question is about types of and cues towards identifying outdated answers. It is not an opinion poll about system changes.

Comment: @bad_coder How is this off-topic? It *is* a suggestion of a cue "towards identifying outdated answers".

Comment: @cb4: green, yellow, red all look very similar to those with the most common form of colour-blindness.

Comment: @TobySpeight Indeed!!! Thanks for the reminder. One of my best friends is red-green color blind and I still often succumb to my subconscious biases. I'm sure the SO team will pick an appropriate implementation for this idea.

Answer (score 6):

The motivating idea seems to fall squarely into begging the question category: underspecified enough to be nigh useless of a concern - since everyone will read into it whatever they have on their mind, and if I was looking for malicious intent I'd just sweep it up as asking leading questions in search of a problem.

My basic premise is: **outdated answers are a narrow category**. First, a value judgment is made *literally* on the date an answer was given. Sure, being *old* is a factual and perhaps non-judgmental observation, yet whether it implies any sort of out-of-date-ness in pejorative sense is a very long leap that better had a good and considerate argument going for it. Out-of-date-ness implies loss of relevance, but it's not a straightforward implication. A slide rule technique doesn't become useless, invalid or "outdated" just because of technological progress someone finally has the choice not to use said slide rule.

Lest I be unclear: a survey is not an argument, in as much as a PowerPoint deck is not an engineering analysis. It may be a prompt, at best, but now this meta question seems to devolve into just a *prompt*. Aren't mere prompts considered low-effort? Is Meta really a place where low-effort questions are to be fleshed out by the community? **I do consider the question to be extremely low-effort, and an XY problem classic to boot.**

There's plenty of nuance as to how age of the old answers affects their usefulness and applicability.

First of all, an answer isn't outdated just because it refers to, say, an older language standard/version or an older version of some software package/library. This would be, after all, placing a value judgement on the **technology** or even **question** - not an answer. A good quality answer about an "outdated" technology is *not by extension outdated itself*: it may well represent the best we know about what now amounts to a historical artifact!

By default, we can't but presume that an answer is as relevant to some "environment version" as it was the day it was posted, even if the version/environment may not be relevant anymore. Let's leave that to be judged by those who look for/need such answers. Lots of people are "stuck" on older development environments (in all imaginable ways - be it compiler versions, language versions, third party library versions, OS versions, hardware being targeted, etc.). They may have little choice in the manner, and while I always think that mainstream development should do its best to reap the benefits of new features and foundational improvements, it'd be extremely short sighted to presume that everyone refuses to upgrade out of mere stubbornness. If anything, there's always some work involved in upgrades, and those holding the paycheck may have some say into what they wish to spend their money on. Or someone may just wish to write stuff in [C++98](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Standardization) out of sheer thrill of it all - who are we to judge? Are all C++98 questions and answers to be made off-topic and relegated to Retrocomputing?

On that note, I personally see Retrocomputing as a targeted conglomerate of [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) and [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour), and a question about, say, dealing with file descriptors on [CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) shouldn't be off-topic on SO just because Retrocomputing exists, lest we face an urgent need to periodically move answers en-masse just because they now seem to touch on an "old" programming topic. That's IMHO a very slippery slope. But hey: you can't pretend that Retrocomputing doesn't exist when asking about "outdated" anything. Tape sorts seem plenty on-topic on SO, since they are genuine algorithmic approaches that often renew their relevancy when facing the complex multi-leveled memory hierarchies. Sequential cache prefetch brings the "historic" tape algorithms into mainstream performance leaders, after all. That's the problem with classifications so loaded and broad that they bring with them indifferent pejorative slant.

There could be some mechanism to **tag the answers** to help resolve this issue with respect to answers narrower than the question itself. Not all questions limit to just one particular "version" of the environment they are set in, often by necessity. Someone asking a C++ question on SO in 2009 didn't have to worry much about [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) if they weren't inquiring specifically about "C++0x" and its standardization/development efforts. There was just "one" C++ back then, not the plethora we have now. Even [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20) and C++11 are sufficiently different to warrant very different idiomatic approaches to common problems - thus a C++20 answer doesn't make a C++11 answer outdated. Even Python 3 was only just about to be released at the end of 2008 - several months after SO was up and running already.

Answers can be on-topic, yet cover vastly different versions, approaches, and methodologies, based on the period they were provided in, or the period they refer to. An arbitrary coverage of some older environment in an answer can't be seen as a negative if the question doesn't limit the solution space. Say, a question may refer to C++ in general, but there may be 3 or 4 or even 20 viable routes for a good answer based on what language version it's set in. If the question doesn't narrow the choice down sufficiently in the *question tags*, it seems that perhaps the *answer tags* could do that job. In that case, sorting by score would need to be by mutually exclusive tags first, e.g. so that a 15-score C++20 answer could be shown next to a 500-score C++98 answer.

Another side of this same coin is an answer that wasn't particularly good *at the time it was provided* and in relation to the version, variant of language, library, and methodology it was set in. It's not automatically a better or worse of an answer just due to passage of time either: it was not good to begin with. There's perhaps a natural tendency to think of those as "outdated" after some times passes, also because the state of the art moves on yet may an answer may remain applicable to the "historic" environment of the question. The potential effect of the motion of state of the art while keeping the historic context fixed requires some care!

Is it valid to call outdated an answer that lost relevancy only in retrospect? Perhaps that's the avenue where it could be a genuine concern. Think of network security, for example. Over time, we develop more knowledge of the past, so, if anything, the solution space of a particular historic problem may become better understood or even a completely new and indisputably better approach may present itself. In *this specific case*, I believe it's valid to argue that an answer has inherently become **outdated**.

But then: what should we do about it - if at all - while having to resort to tools not already within our toolbox? If I run past an answer suggesting to build up SQL queries by string concatenation in a way that is a SQL injection free-for-all, I'd expect anyone to downvote it because we generally know a lot better than to commit such atrocities. Should anything *else* or *extra* be done about such an answer, though? Now consider a slightly different answer that doesn't commit any security atrocities, but simply provides a technique that has much better alternatives nowadays - let's presume that such alternatives carry back and apply to the historical context of the answer. It may well be considered "outdated" by the criterion I proposed, but does it warrant downvotes or any other special action? And especially if no better answer exists? It is a presumed ideal that answers are judged in isolation from each other, but that's not how life works at all, and it's IMHO an unrealistic standard. Answers are voted for by humans, and ultimately a significantly better or even more flashy or better presenting answer can always cast neighboring perfectly acceptable and reasonable answers in "bad light". So, if anything, there *already is some pressure that favors the newer/more modern approaches*, and voting bears this out. Do we need any special nails in the coffin to further underscore the difference? I'm yet to see any well-reasoned argument for it.

Comment: This is obviously a very good in-depth post. Maybe the right place for it would be [on the other thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302). This thread is more specific about the questions in the survey that's about to be made. I think perhaps the best would be to delete the post here and copy it to the other thread?

Answer (score 4):

> 2. Which factors help you determine that an answer is outdated?

I would suggest having as option content of the answer itself by way of:

> 2.7. Technical content of the answer (e.g. outdated syntax, outdated documentation links, etc...)

Answer (score -2):

The problem with the original question is that it specifies a cut-off date by which all later answers may be ignored. And that date is specified by a staff member to be one week after she asked the question.

That is not how Stack Overflow works. It takes time to discover questions and the best answers are discovered by democratic vote over time.

Secondly, as [Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1329652/kuba-hasnt-forgotten-monica) [points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405530/11573842), this question begs the question. It presupposes that there is a problem with "outdated answers". An answer isn't outdated just because there are later versions of a language, a library, an environment, or a technique and the answer doesn't apply to them if it works for those who are still using the version for which the answer is addressed. Many users of outdated versions of X have been pleased to discover answers that no longer apply to the latest and greatest but do apply to the version they are stuck using.

Answer (score -5):

From the question it isn't entirely clear if bullet point `3.` has a set of options or is meant for open answers. Does it repeat the options in `2.`?

Even if we're near the dead-line (or past it) it would be interessting to see these options explicitly. And some community posts about them.

> 3. What do you currently do when you encounter an outdated answer?