# Embed image syntax is made too complicated

Tags: support, images

When you embed an image, SO automatically types this:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: https://.....
```

Why isn't the `[` at the beginning removed, as well as the `][1]` at the end of the line? It works perfectly and is, for me, more understandable, less messy:

```
![enter image description here][1]

  [1]: https://.....
```

Or even:

```
![enter image description here](https://.....)
```

Comment: The first makes the image a link to itself (clickable), while the second just shows the image

Comment: But `![enter image description here][1]` does work?

Comment: And why do we need to click on the image? Isn't it almost always big enough?

Comment: @D_00 to make it larger, because no it's not always large enough

Comment: And if it's automatically inserted by the editor when **you click a button**... why do you care if it's "complicated" or not?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362397/do-we-really-need-linked-images

Comment: @Nick even if an image fits the post, there is no downside to allow easily opening it *anyway*. You might want it in a separate window. I do that often when I want to open an image for reference on another monitor. For example [Outdated Answers: results from use-case survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406675) has a bunch of graphs that I want to be able to glance at after I've scrolled to a different location in the page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The former makes the image clickable as a link to itself:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

While the latter simply embeds it in the page:

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

[image]