# How bad does any answer need to be to warrant flagging under the outdated answer project?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, outdated-answer

I'm feeling some hesitation on flagging an accepted answer on the basis of either "Newer, more efficient" or "poses a risk", and would like to have further elaboration on the criteria for flagging *accepted* answers when other answers might be slightly more efficient or slightly less risky.

I'm considering the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33167064/1497199) regarding putting data into a CSV format.  The accepted answer is correct in that it solves the OP's specific question (hence accepted).  However, as indicated in the comment, and the other answer to this question, there is a more robust way of solving the problem that should work in general.  Using `StringIO` is probably more efficient, but for small files, not by enough to be a big deal.  Similarly, using CSV is a bit safer in terms of handling things that can mess up CSV formatting.  But, in my opinion, neither are deal-breakers for the use case exemplified in the question.

In my mind, the accepted answer is not "outdated" in that it does solve the OP's problem, even though there are better ways to skin this cat.

Though the accepted answer is sub-optimal relative to the other one, I thought that the point of having separate "accepted" and "upvote" options was precisely to preserve the information on which answers were actually used; so I'm particularly suspicious of flagging accepted answers.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is related to the [outdated answer project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407613/outdated-accepted-answers-flagging-exercise-has-begun) prompt, correct? IMO this is a case of an answer that was always just a poor answer.

Comment: Yes, it's related to the outdated answer flagging exercise, and my concern/uncertainty applies to accepted answers in particular.

Comment: Pretty sure that both the community and stack have no desire to *"remove"* any content at all, the sentiment of not wanting content removed was in both the top voted comment and answer of the [original announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project)

Comment: The flag is not about "bad"/"good", it is about "out-of-date"/"not-out-of-date".

Comment: This new system is very bad as it provokes witch hunts

Comment: @HereticMonkey "newer, more efficient answers exist" and "Answer poses security risk..." read to me to be reasons why an answer would be considered bad, not just out of date.

Comment: @Dave Sure, but that's what the flag is *about*, as in, its primary purpose. And I would say that "newer, more efficient answers exist" does not automatically make an answer bad. Personally, I prefer seeing code like `var found = "find Waldo".indexOf("Waldo") !== -1;` because I know `indexOf` returns -1 when the string is not found. Maybe `var found = ~"find Waldo".indexOf("Waldo");` is more "efficient" but it's far too clever for its own good. Of course now I'd use `"find Waldo".includes("Waldo")` and call it a day :).

Comment: @Nick remember that comments can't be downvoted.

Comment: @Braiam What's your point?

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer *only* mattered for the OP.

If the OP accepted an answer that is either *now* dangerous or is bad, or was always bad, the only thing that matters is that we flag it and deal with it accordingly with respect to dealing with outdated answers.

Do not let the green check mark interfere with your conviction that the answer you're examining is outdated.