# Is there a userscript to sort answers?

Tags: support, answers, sorting

According [this research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407613/outdated-accepted-answers-flagging-exercise-has-begun?cb=1), some people want to change the way answers are sorted on this site.

I am one of those people, and I'd even like the answers to be sorted differently depending on what I am looking for:

- in general, I want to look at the accepted answer
- then, I look at the highest voted answer
- sometimes, I want to look at the newest answer, especially if the highest voted answer is old. This often applies to Git questions where there seems to be breaking changes somewhere around 2009. It also applies to C++ questions older than 2011.
- in most cases, I want to hide deleted answers, but sometimes, I even have a look at these. (Just like [XKCD 979](https://xkcd.com/979/))

I wonder whether someone has already written a userscript to change the way answers are sorted. Ideally, it would allow me to make the changes quickly, but even if there's one script per purpose, that would be great.

Comment: https://stackapps.com/questions/8912/sort-best-first

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: that one looks fine at a first glance. Thanks!

Comment: Other than hiding deleted answers, which are sorted to the end and can be easily ignored in the "Votes" sort (or add a bit of CSS to hide them), your bullet points of desired sorting describes the sort options which are available for answers in the stock pages without modification. Those options are "Active", "Oldest", and "Votes". Admittedly, the "Active" sort is a bit different from "Newest", but it's fairly close, and may be closer to what you actually want (most recently updated). I'm all for userscripts (I use >100 of them), but it's unclear what you want that's not already available.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Then either I've had something special going on for years by SE (ever since I had 10k; not a userscript doing it), or you're not looking at the "Votes" sort. The other two sort options don't sort deleted questions to the end of the page. Here are some direct links to an example question with a high-scored deleted answer: [Active](//stackoverflow.com/q/1986896?answertab=active), [Oldest](//stackoverflow.com/q/1986896?answertab=oldest), [Votes](//stackoverflow.com/q/1986896?answertab=votes). SE remembers your last sort selection and will open any new questions with that sort.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm just dumb and never saw that there are options for changing the sort order already:

[image]

I think we should have a badge for using these :-)

Thanks to [Makyen♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3773011/makyen) for pointing that out.

I'm really sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Not a problem. Don't worry about it. We all, from time to time, become blind to things we see hundreds, thousands, tens of thousands, or even more, times. If people have other sort requirements/desires and know of a userscript which provides that sorting, then it could be helpful to have that known.