# Feeling under some kind of attack

Tags: support, downvotes, old-questions

I have a [very old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648275/display-custom-header-or-column-in-windows-explorer/9654420#9654420) that I know to be right. It was there for 9 years, slowly gathering a humble 16 upvotes and not a single downvote. Suddenly during the last month, it was downvoted 5 times. Then my other answer, also a very old one that was never downvoted before, was downvoted.

I do not really care about points but I would like to know what is going on because in a way I feel threatened. In all my 10 years on SO that never happened before.

Comment: @Paulie_D linking to the specific questions would run the risk of the "meta effect" kicking in and possibly result in more downvotes.

Comment: @Paulie_D - it's pretty easy to find, check their reputation tab. Although that doesn't matter much since the OP updated the question.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have thought moderators can see it without me linking it. Anyway, added the link.

Comment: @Flot2011 - everyone can see it :) Your activity is public (unless the post is deleted, but all 10K+ users can see those too), but it takes some time and effort to find the post (that's probably a good thing). It does look like the answer just got some exposure over the past months that for some reason was mostly negative.

Comment: It looks like a new answer has been posted fairly recently that apparently people are finding superior (just based on looking at votes and not reading them yet)

Comment: The new answer does contradict your one on the topic of whether property handlers can be implemented in managed code . If you are sure it can be done despite Microsoft apparently saying it can't  perhaps add the relevant code to your answer

Comment: I wonder if this is a side effect of the current [Outdated Answers "experiment"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407613/8967612) (which would not necessarily be a bad thing).

Comment: Downvotes are not personal attacks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the question, I'd say you've been upstaged by a newer answer. [This answer was posted on Feb 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66017828/2370483) and it appears to target Windows 10. Your answer targets Windows XP (because it's 9 years old). Your answer also relies heavily on a link, while the other answer is rich in details in the answer itself.

Since Feb 2, the question has been favorited 4 times. I'd say this old question simply found a new lease on life thanks to a new answer. It's not uncommon for an outdated answer to be downvoted, as that's the only way to indicate usefulness currently ([something SO is trying to change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project))

Comment: "because it's 9 years old" If the answer was 19 years old targeting XP would be reasonable (released Oct 2001) , Vista was 2006 and Win 7 in 2009 though. The part of the answer that was supposed to apply to later OS looks potentially incorrect if the other answer is right that "property handlers cannot be implemented in managed code and should be implemented in C++."

Comment: OK, I see it now, thanks. There is an interesting problem though - when given, the answer was 100% correct and useful. I cannot update it because I m working now in a totally different field, so I am being "punished" for exactly what? A technological change?

Comment: @Flot2011 - yeah, more or less because of that, nothing to be done, users vote as they please. Don't treat it as "punishment", you just got a bad streak. I see it has been upvoted at least twice recently, so it is not a guarantee that it will continue to be downvoted. Presently, you are also experiencing the "Meta Effect" from exposing the answer with a direct link on Meta.

Comment: @Flot2011 probably the reason that your answer is getting down votes is that currently it indicates that property handlers would be the solution in Vista or later, whereas the other answer indicates pursuing this idea from .NET would be a wild goose chase. Maybe your answer is correct but following the now dead links in the comments doesn't give any example of this

Answer (score 9):

There is no evidence you have been targeted with down-votes. I can't judge the accuracy of your answer, but it could be that people just don't find it helpful for what ever reason.

Comment: If it was downvoted during a relatively long period of time I would say you are right. But not a single downvote for 9 years and then 5 in one month?

Comment: @Flot2011 A new answer was added to the post in february which will've bumped it up the active list, it has also been edited multiple times since then resulting in recent exposure to your answer, seems normal to me