# "Is this answer outdated" shows on new answers to old questions

Tags: bug, answers, outdated-answer

As the title says, the "Is this answer outdated?" prompt shows on all answers to old questions, regardless of when they were posted. This came to my attention when I was prompted if my own answer from 10 minutes ago was outdated:
[image]

If you want to investigate yourself, [here's the link to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40907897/5923139).

This probably has a very small impact, but it would be nice to have it addressed (maybe answers within a year shouldn't have this prompt?). Also, answering "yes" should have a different effect when it's on your own answer, since you can do much more than just flag it (e.g. editing the answer to include a disclaimer).

Comment: Showing it on your own answer also seems a bit like an anti-pattern.

Comment: @CodyGray Not necessarily, if the answer is old enough it may be outdated. What doesn't make sense is showing it on new answers. But it is hard to nitpick about behavior that is not available at large and is not completely clear how will it eventually work.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar But, why would you choose to indicate that on your own answer, instead of either (A) fixing it or (B) deleting it? Otherwise, all valid points.

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe you don't have time to fix it, maybe you no longer work with technology... marking it as outdated makes sense to me. The way I see it, outdated answers is not about removing good answers that were valid for some technology at some point in time and that are still valuable to those using older technologies for whatever reason, but to make it easier to find newer answers which is usually what most people look for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be by design, however strange it may seem. This is how the criteria [were defined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407613/11407695) when the "flagging exercise" began on May 13th:

> The prompts have a chance to appear when the question is at least 60 days old and there are at least two answers to the question. If you indicate that the answer is outdated, a modal appears that asks you to select various reasons why the answer is outdated.

The question you linked to was asked in 2016 so it definitely qualifies for the 60 days threshold. It also has 4 undeleted answers, which is certainly more than the 2 required.

You are just a (lucky?) one to land into the "1% of the time" sampling while browsing an old question matching the criteria and where you left an answer. The latter is not taken into account and was confirmed by a staff member in comments:

[image: staff response if answers are taken into account]

Plaintext version:

> With regards to seeing it on answers that are less than 60 days old, whether to display the prompt is decided at the question level. If the question qualifies, all answers will have the prompt regardless of age. Where 60 days comes in is that a question has to have 2 or more answers, one of which has to be an accepted answer 60 days old or older. – Brian Nickel♦ May 20 at 20:03

Comment: "This bug is not a bug because it is by design." Of course, why didn't I think of that. :-)