# Why is there no privilege for being able to change the accepted answer to a question?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, privileges

I just noticed that my next 2 milestones (and the only ones left) don't allow me to do the one thing I really want to do, which is, have the privilege to change the accepted answer on questions where the accepted answer is clearly not the best/correct one.

Here's my proposal for being able to change an accepted answer:

1. The answer you want to accept needs to be either 100 upvotes or double the upvotes of the currently accepted answer (whichever is less).
2. The user who asked the question hasn't made any other contributions (or maybe hasn't logged in) in more than a year.

This privilege should be high. Maybe at the 50k or 100k point level?

I'd personally find this motivating.

Comment: Solution: don't associate too much value with the green checkmark next to the answer. The accepted answer is [already unpinned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/8967612) and is [in the process of being unpinned on other sites too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568).

Comment: Relevant: [Outdated Answers: accepted answer is now unpinned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/11682469)

Comment: I feel as though the new unpinning of the accepted essentially accomplishes this, It doesn't get the checkmark but we'll see with the new tracking pixel data if people search that out or just the top answer.

Comment: I think it's the size of the green checkmark that bothers me.

Comment: OK. I'll let it go. I guess this is a bad idea.

Comment: *"Why is there no privilege for being able to change the accepted answer to a question?"* - Technically, there is, it's the author of the questions privilege

Comment: I've rolled back your latest edit. While I understand it feels bad to have a post downvoted, the downvotes are for the post, not you personally. And you may get downvotes because users disagree with the ideas in your post, and not necessarily because of its quality. Also, unlike the main site, downvotes on meta questions have no material effect whatsoever, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: For what it's worth: I don't agree with your proposal, but you are not alone in being irked by the question acceptance feature. In my opinion it needs to be changed in how it is presented. Definitely not with a green "Correct!" checkmark. A small thumbs up icon would be more appropriate, given that it is basically no more than an endorsement from the question author.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Because that's what voting is for

Ever since [the accepted answer was unpinned from the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/208273), the community has the ability to change the order of answers by voting on them.  In this way, it can be decided collaboratively, rather than possibly devolving into fights between high-rep users over where the checkmark should go (fights that moderators without subject-matter expertise in some subjects would be ill-equipped to resolve).