# Is demanding answer unaccepting acceptable?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

Sometimes you stumble upon questions that are exactly what you want to know and since we want to keep this site from having x duplicate questions you don't want to ask your own, of course.

The problem is that some of these questions have answers marked as accepted that don't answer the **actual** question.

Is there a way to flag such answer to demand **unaccepting**, not being the user who asked the question?

Because, in my humble opinion, there should be.
Or should we simply propose an edit that shifts the question towards the accepted answer? What do you think?

Comment: Downvote the answer. As simple as that.

Comment: The check mark just means that was what worked best for the OP, and they are entitled to decide that for themselves. It does not necessarily mean it's the best answer. That's what the votes are for.

Comment: @GinoMempin I get what you mean, it's just that *in my opinion* that pretty much contradicts stackoverflow's efforts of both **reducing duplicates** and **clearly marking or reducing subjective content** . Since in the end, while i can't talk for everybody, I want search engines to find the ONE or two helpful answer(s) when it's a specific questions and not see only the 10 ones above it that answered mentioned thing B instead of asked thing A, but yeah.. May be subjective.

Comment: You could also place a bounty on the question saying you're looking for answers that actually address thing A instead of B.

Comment: I don't quite understand how unaccepting the accepted answer helps in "*reducing duplicates*". All the answers should be taken into account when checking if the question is a duplicate. It's a duplicate because it was already asked before and there are already answers for it, possibly multiple answers, _not just the accepted answer_. There was even a recent change that [unpinned the accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/2745495) which hopefully de-emphasizes it, and letting the highest voted ones be more prominent instead.

Comment: As for "*clearly marking or reducing subjective content*", that's what votes are for. Users can upvote on the answers they found useful, and downvote those that they conside4 wrong or unhelpful. The acceptance of the OP is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Gino nailed it. In the old days (last year) when the checkmark pinned an answer to the top for all time (there's a good chance OP left the site, never to return, after adding a checkmark), there was a lot of pressure to @ OP and beg them to unpin so hapless users wouldn't wind up using whatever potentially damaging/outdated advice was in the accepted/top answer. But now green checkmark answers aren't pinned and are so much less prone to spreading misinformation. (In practice, outdated answers with too many upvotes to counteract spread misinformation; the trending vote tries to resolve this).

Answer (score 20):

Accepting an answer is a mark of approval from the original question asker. It doesn't mean that the answer works or is even a solution to the problem. Unless you are the original author of the question, you can't change this mark of approval. Even mods can't change it.

If the answer is wrong, downvote it. If you think the answer deserves deletion then cast your delete vote too (20k+ reputation).

Comment: Can a negatively scored accepted answer be deleted through votes?

Comment: @Lino Yes, but not my the author