# What should I do if someone un-accepts the only answer (with many upvotes) for no apparent reason after a long time?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, unaccepted-answer

I would like to have some advice on what would be right to do (or not to) in those situations, and some opinions, especially on the **last part of the question**.

I spent quite some time on answering a question and refining it (almost one hour, which is not too much, but not too little either) to add references and a working example, and which I think addressed the question 100%.

My answer was the only one, I got some upvotes (4 to be precise - so I think there are people who found it useful as well), and I got the answer accepted from the OP the same day or the day after.

Today, more than a week later, the OP un-accepted the answer, without saying anything, not a single comment, nor an edit.

I don't live to get reputation score, but that seems quite unfair, since there seems to be no valid reason to do that.

Was it a mistake, was it on purpose? Should I ask for clarifications in a comment? Or should I just forget it and go on?
Wouldn't it be better if users had to **provide a motivation** to un-accept an answer, which would be then delegated along with the notification?

Comment: Oh..., "Poor thing", don't worry, I spend 10h when I post a "[Quality Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68473816/3799241)" on this Site for the small Tag I answer, and I'm always already happy when my Answers don't get roomba'd together with the Qt's (Qt = Question), (mostly 1-Rep Users in "my" Tag, who rarely accept an Answer and can't even upvote), so be happy with the '+4' you got on that Answer, and the "Satisfaction" that you helped 4 or 5 Users at least, ah-ah...!

Comment: Remember that the person who asked the question is the last person in the world qualified to know the correct or even the best answer, by definition. For many people anything that even appears to work seems to be sufficient. By the same token theirs are the last actions you should be worried about.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The same thing you should do if your answer doesn't get accepted in the first place:

#### Nothing.

Your main concern shouldn't be pleasing the asker or getting his/her approval. Write your answers so that the community at large benefits from them. You say your answer has received a few upvotes, which means other users have found it useful. It doesn't really matter that much whether the OP accepts the answer or not.

Comment: My main doubt was that maybe it would be less visible, but probably leaving a comment wouldn't make sense anyways, since it was a casual user. Thank you for the reply, I really appreciate it

Comment: @mikyll98 Note that the accepted answer is [no longer pinned to the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/8967612) on Stack Overflow anyway.