# A user marked his own answer as correct after marking mine

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer

I invested in checking a user's question. He marked my answer as correct, and then after two days he suddenly wrote an explanation that was not at all clear and unhelpful that he got it right and passed the marking of the answer to himself.

Does it make sense that a user marks that I helped him, and then decides to write down just some sentence to give himself the points? [This is the link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74000641/values-from-array-only-change-upon-first-run-of-a-function/74000693#74000693)

Comment: @HaimAbeles- If the answer is incorrect, incomplete, or you simply find it unhelpful you should downvote.

Comment: "He marked my answer as correct" - there is no such feature in this site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I understand why it feels wrong or frustrating, but you need to keep in mind what acceptance is for.

As stated on the [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"? Help Center page](/help/accepted-answer):

> **Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly**. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally. Not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they might not change the accepted answer even if a newer, better answer comes along later.

The specific question doesn't matter; your answer could be *infinitely* better in every way, more eloquent, more useful, more comprehensive– but the question author, the OP, always has the right to choose any posted answer, including their own, as their accepted one, to mark that "this helped me" or "I liked this one the best".

If you don't like their answer, find it unclear or not useful, you're welcome to [downvote it](/help/privileges/vote-down). If you feel you could improve the answer to make it clearer, you can [edit it](/help/editing). But at the end of the day, question authors' acceptance doesn't mean that much– the most important way content is ranked on Stack Exchange is through community upvotes and downvotes, not green checkmarks (especially now that [accepted answers aren't pinned to the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352)).

Answer (score 14):

You can accept your own answer, [but you're not awarded any reputation for it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/175248).  So, there's no scenario in which the user gives themselves points.

It also makes sense to do this if an earlier answer gave someone *more* information to then form a more complete answer.

Comment: I would love to hear more opinions because maybe I'm just hurting for my reputation, does the user's answer explain something about the question?

Comment: Honestly?  I've seen answers like that all the time.  "Oh, it wasn't this, it was that."  No big deal IMO.  The OP found a solution that worked for them and decided to share it.