# What was wrong with this suggested edit, which added an explanation for the code in an answer?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-suspension

This isn't just me. The same mod in question here has been doing this on many edits ([another meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420323/ive-been-suspended-from-reviewing-after-correct-revisions) was asked just after this one, with the suspension there being 2 months, instead of 2 days.)

---

I recently got suspended from reviewing suggested edits because two edits that had been approved in the review queue got rejected and rolled back by a moderator about a week later.

I don't mind the suspension, but I'm a bit confused as to why I was suspended.

This is the edit I'm talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32614730

The answer was originally just a block of code. This edit added an explanation about how it worked.

Quoting from [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

> Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better

Surely this was an explanation.

[The OP even commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73556636/python-regex-pattern-matching/73556823#comment129894369_73556823) on that answer, asking *"Why does this work"* (direct quote from OP's comment)

In my opinion (and another reviewer's opinion as well), this was a good edit.

I approved it on August 31st. The next day, another reviewer approved it.

However, on September 9th, a moderator rejected it, and it got rolled back.

Can someone explain why this was not a good edit?

---

P.S. The [other edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32569188) I reviewed was, again, approved in the queue, and then rejected by the same mod.

Comment: Since when does an edit by the original poster has to be approved? I also don't see what's wrong with the edit. I'm confused.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Not the same user (account). [gatete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19887797/gatete) vs [gatete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19887808/gatete)

Comment: @Ivar - Thx, that's a strange coincidence.

Comment: In fact they might be the same person, notice that one of them is an [unregistered user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262909/how-do-unregistered-accounts-work)

Comment: While this question is a dupe, I disagree with the accepted answer and would consider this case an example of why the accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: Don't change the author's intent. Don't change code. Don't approve that.

Comment: If there's something like a missing brace at the end or a missing include at the top of a code block, and it clearly has nothing to with the problem I generally add it.

Comment: The relative difference in user ID between the two accounts is 0.00006%... (That is over 14 years, but still. It corresponds to about 4 minutes (if it was linear).)

Comment: @PeterMortensen There was 80 seconds between the accounts being created, account creation time is in the tooltip for the text saying how long they've been on the site.

Comment: The question isn't great in the first place IMO. It's not entirely clear what the *question* is; I just see an apparently undesired output and a vague description of various attempts to solve the problem. Then there's the part where empty lists in the output are described as "random brackets", which suggests a lack of any attempt to debug or otherwise understand the problem.

Comment: In the other edit, why didn't either of the approvers fix the weird *"The following images"* sentence fragment? The other images....what? Also, if an answer needs to be updated every time there's a new release then they should have created a community wiki.

Comment: I've had a similarly poor experience with reviewing suggested edits recently. I was suspended for three edits which a mod disagreed with. I can see their reasoning, but in all three cases my review decision was my honest best effort based on the available information and my interpretation of the guidelines. Reviewing edits isn't fun, or even really possible at all, if the rules are opaque, inflexible and rigidly enforced. Sure, change my edit decision, but don't suspend me for acting in good faith. Just tell me how I can do better next time.

Comment: I really cannot for the life of me see how rejecting edits like this makes SO a better place. It seems to very clearly make the post better and there's no ambiguity about explaining how code works - that's not conflicting with anything.

Comment: Maybe the mod thought the user was a fake account trying to look like the OP. Why *are* there two accounts anyway?

Comment: I think it's kinda weird for a mod to come along and undo these kinds of edits, as long as the edits are edits that aren't detrimental. The author of the post can revert it instantly if they decide the explanation that was added is insufficient or not what they intended. It's not yet at a point where mod intervention is necessary.

Comment: @KevinB I agree. I thought that the going policy with borderline or controversial edits was roughly "only step in when it's obvious", or only taking binding action on especially egregious cases. Maybe Zoe thought this was one of those cases, but this seems pretty steep for an action that the community apparently considers controversial at best (as indicated by the answer scores below).

Comment: Approving edits is sort of "all or nothing". Adding the explanation likely wasn't the issue, that's the good part, but changing the code, i.e. the variable name, was a completely unnecessary change. Sure, renaming a variable ultimately doesn't change the meaning of the code, but it doesn't improve it at all either. In other words, it's a superfluous edit. If I'd seen this while it was still awaiting approvers I'd probably have selected "approve with improvements" to undo the code change part.

Comment: @philipxy The only code change appears to be fixing the file name *to what the question OP actually showed* - the "test2.txt" was a mistake and should have been "test.txt" all along.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Then the editor should have said so in the summary. Re the reject, I expect the mod considered the prose contrary to poster's intent. BTW There is an active meta question re whether it's good to "explain" code-only answer code.

Comment: er, I'm not quite decided about the first edit, but the second one is certainly not something that deserves to be accepted. the editor added *plenty* of stuff that does not come from the OP. Imo if you routinely accept such edits you indeed need to think again.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier Agreed, the second one was a complete overhaul of the answer.

Comment: Boy, oh, boy.  If nothing else, this thread makes me feel even less guilty that I spend no time reviewing edits.  Do I have this right?  Person A posted a code-only answer.  Person B (who might have been person A under a slightly different username) augmented the code with some explanations.  Person C approved the edit.  Somehow this was such a wrong thing to do that moderator D came along and *blocked person C for his trouble*.  And now quite a few of the commentators on this thread are *agreeing with moderator D*.  The "hate" part of my love-hate relationship with SO is confirmed.

Comment: @SteveSummit You seem to operate under the impression that effort/trouble == valuable. not saying anything about this specific post, but it's a patently wrong way to evaluate things. people go through great trouble to make abolutely worthless content daily. the simple fact that an action is posed does not mean it is good. there are edits that deserve bans, *even after some people reviewed them*. again, not saying this is the case here, but the implication that mods blocking people from revieweing is never justified is just extremely tiring, and objectively wrong.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier Sorry, I made the implicit assumption in my comment that person B's edit was useful and made in good faith.  Nowhere did I mean to suggest that bad edits ought to be retained just to reward the work that went into them.

Comment: Moderators shouldn't (ab)use their power like this. They should only use their powers, when the community can't handle it. They should be exception handlers, and not pro queue cleaners. [It never ends well. This isn't the first time, a moderator went overboard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401752)

Comment: Interesting that we haven't yet heard from the mod in question. I would like to hear their side of the story.

Comment: @MattDMo I have nothing to add beyond [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416123/6296561),  which established a consensus. I've featured that post to give y'all an opportunity to change the consensus (read: I'm not going to argue about it here because it's already argued for me elsewhere), but it was regardless the consensus at the time of the review suspension

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine, do you think the help page gives conflicting advice on this subject, then? (see the quotation in this question's accepted answer)

Comment: @TheThonnu I don't. See the linked answer, particularly the third and fourth sentences. The help center gives advice that's far too open to interpretation, however; see the last paragraph. (As an aside, problems open to interpretation or with no answer at all is what we have meta for)

Comment: There are two questions at play here: "is this a type of edit we would like to be accepted", and "might a reviewer, following the review guidelines on the help page, reasonably accept this edit". It's very possible to answer no to the first and yes to the second, which would yield a strong argument for changing the help page. In practice it looks like there are voices on both sides of both questions, which could mean it's destined to remain unclear. I think it's very important to keep the two questions distinct, though. For the sanity of the reviewers as much as anything else.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Would you say that, once again, the Help Centre is doing the opposite of what its name suggests? (Tongue-in-cheek, I don't expect you to answer that!)

Comment: and some do not understand why the queues are full, that less and less are willing to edit/review.... :-/

Comment: May I also add that it's quite exemplary moderation to just enforce policies established by community consensus (a meta answer with +92 is a pretty strong community consensus), rather than to try to whittle out some personal interpretation from broad, subjective and often unclear help pages. On similar sites like Codidact, moderators have the ability to edit help pages, so that community consensus from meta _becomes_ the help. Here on SO we are at the mercy at the whims from individual SO employees who may change the help text at any point, without even discussing it with the community.

Comment: @Lundin that makes sense to me, and I'm happy with the idea of mods making decisions about edits based on community consensus. Thanks for the explanation about not being able to edit the help pages. What doesn't work for me is applying the same logic to reviewer suspension decisions. Reviewers are shown the help page when they open the review queue. They're told when they're suspended that it's because they didn't follow the instructions, and are asked to read the help page again. It's like trying to play a football game where the players have been given a different rulebook from the referee.

Comment: @Sam Indeed. Also there's a parallel discussion about suggested review edits going on here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420349/reviewer-overboard-or-a-request-to-improve-the-onboarding-guidance-for-new-revi. Hopefully this will boil down to better instructions and then maybe the mods involved can pass it along to a CM to get the help pages changed.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine 136 saying X and 105 saying not X is not a consensus.  136 saying X and 105 saying not X is a slim majority in one Q&A.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont at the time of writing, the votes were far more in favor of not editing. The ratio has changed since I featured it; that doesn't change the validity of the statement _when I wrote it_. It's also still at 66% against editing (net votes, assumes 0 overlap which I can't confirm), which isn't as slim as you make it out to be

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Based on my reading of the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits), [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32614730) was okay and your decision was not incorrect.

Under "Common reasons to approve," the help page says that you **should approve** an edit if it

> Adds additional information or clarifies existing answer

This is **exactly** what the edit did. The explanation that was added by the edit constitutes additional information which clarified the existing answer.

Other reviewers rejected the change, apparently because they believed that it deviated from the original intent. By my reading of the guidelines, the edit does not meet that criterion. Under "Common reasons to Reject," the help page says that you should reject an edit under this criterion if it "clearly conflicts with author’s intent," which is clarified as

> changes a post to say the opposite, or something very different from what the original post read.

The edit did not change the intent of the post to something very different or opposite from its original text. In fact, practically all of the original text was retained.

I initially said that "all of the original text was retained," but I want to thank the commenters who noted that there is a small meaningful change to the original answer text, where the filename `test2.txt` is corrected to `test.txt`. This correction makes the code in the answer a closer match for the code in the original question. Approving edits which fix small mistakes is encouraged by the review guidelines.

Comment: +1 for actually referring back to the actual help page which is what should be used as a reference for these kind of disputes

Comment: Sure, they added additional information for clarity. They also edited code which wasn't necessary to improve any understanding of it or the issue. Perhaps the author *clearly* intended the variable name.

Comment: For me, changing `test2.txt` to `test.txt` could easily count as "fixing a minor mistake" (see Common reasons to Approve). I say that because the question has `test.txt`, so it seems correct to match that. But I agree it's not clear cut. I'd still say that the edit "improves the post" and does not "clearly conflict with the author's intent". I don't say that I would have made that edit myself. Just that the review task was carried out correctly based on the instructions given.

Comment: I am still unconvinced that suggested edits that require domain knowledge are good idea on a site where the queue is frequently full. This kind of edit can only be approved by someone who can tell whether or not the edit is actually correct.  Burnination efforts often involve tag only edits (sometimes there really is nothing else to fix) but we still ask folks under 2K rep not to flood the queue with those edits.

Comment: @Sam "test2.txt" to "text.txt" is a simple text change in a string in what appears to be a file name, how is it even possible for anyone *other than* the author to determine this string value is a mistake without looking over their shoulder and inspecting their filesystem?

Comment: Ok, I see now where `"text.txt"` is specified in the original *question*. I do then now tend to agree with the code edit to align with the code example provided by the question's OP. The editor should have specified more than just `"Explanation"` as for the reason/justification for the edit *as-a-whole*. Think of the edit message as a "commit message" so the intent of the edit is clear to ***all*** future readers.

Comment: @BSMP New users are correctly encouraged by the Help Centre to helpfully edit posts in order to obtain reputation. The fact that the edit queue is constantly full is a problem of resources and site management, not the new user attempting to contribute positively to the site.

Comment: @IanKemp The Help Center *does not* say or even suggest that any and all edits are valid. We don't allow edits that would change an incorrect answer into a correct one because it would conflict with intent. We don't allow suggested edits of under 6 characters, even though it's often possible for a post to have typos of one or two characters. We absolutely have rules on this site that exist for practical and logistical reasons.

Comment: @IanKemp What do you mean? That’s just how the queue works. If you don’t have the edit privilege then your edit goes into the queue. If the queue is full then you can’t suggest an edit. The system literally doesn’t allow it. That’s *why* I’m asking if edits that can’t be reviewed by most people are a good idea. It prevents suggested edits when full; it doesn’t get infinitely big.

Comment: *"**When can I not suggest an edit?** We stop accepting edits for many reasons, including but not limited to: There are too many suggested edits pending on your site, i.e. the suggested edit review queue is full....500 on Stack Overflow, for the site's suggested edits queue."* https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/293308

Answer (score 4):

I understand that this question already shows a heavy sentiment against how this edit was reviewed, but at least I ought to provide my own reasoning.

As one of the reviewers of the [first suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32614730), in retrospective, I probably would have acted differently on it, but what's particularly confounding here is that someone went out of their way to extend a code-only answer to include a thorough explanation in their own words. It is confounding because at that point, the editor at hand was almost in a better condition to post a *new answer* to question with that explanation, than to modify an existing answer. And one would then let voting do the rest.

Again, I understand that some would disagree with this reasoning, and I admit that rejecting it was probably not in everyone's best interest. Still, I feel that we should not overlook the threshold up to which a contribution could stand by itself. The [second suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32569188) is *very extensive*. At that point, why is this an edit and not an answer by its own? An eventual update to a technology in a way which might partially or completely invalidate an existing answer once someone wants to use a different version is a perfect reason to post a new one, and in my opinion, that edit goes way beyond what the original author intended to do. I wouldn't be surprised if the reviewers felt the same way about this one.

Even if we keep intent out of this, why are people investing so much on piggybacking thorough extensions to an existing non-community wiki answer? In such cases, participants may contribute with an independent answer, potentially garnering their own source of reputation, and without requiring a review step.
The accepted answer is also no longer pinned to the top, and work is under way towards making trending answers have a better chance of being seen. And even so, it should not be asking too much of visitors to scroll half a page.

In short, while the first suggested edit doesn't seem farfetched and I should probably have some more leeway on extending answers with explanations in the future, there are non-insignificant situations in which one should consider posting a new answer over editing an existing one.
This, or just let someone with the edit privilege do that kind of maintenance.

Comment: `why are people investing so much on piggybacking thorough extensions to an existing non-community wiki answer?` Because Stack Overflow already suffers from too many answers. People searching for a solution to their problem generally want **one** good answer, not 15 different ones that they have to pick through to find the most correct one for their situation/time.

Comment: ``the editor at hand was almost in a better condition to post a new answer to question with that explanation`` I don't see why this is any better than just editing the post. As Ian mentioned, surely it is preferrable to keep the post cleaner with fewer, polished answers than various half-arsed answers that clutter up the question, which may or may not get downvoted enough to be deleted.

Comment: I stand with the opinion that we should not be too uptight by the idea of a question collecting more than the "one answer to rule them all". It feels overly idealistic and it's not something that approving suggested edits is going to fix completely, or make things substantially different in that regard. Efforts seem to be much better spent curating the too many questions on the site (a much greater problem than too many answers) and voting on answers.

Comment: An edit isn't *always* the right thing to do, sometimes posting a new answer is better.  In the first review, an edit was better, IMO, since it's just making that answer what it should have been in the first place.  Nobody's arguing that questions should only have one answer, and we should always edit, just that it's not good to have multiple *very similar* answers, especially ones that copy (with attribution) the code from an existing answer just to add some straightforward non-controversial text explanation to it.

Comment: But you're making that "one answer to rule them all" point about the second edit, which yeah added a whole new section with a 2022 update.  The question only had one answer, so not cluttered, and the edit didn't have to change much of anything about the existing answer, just added a whole new answer.  I'm very strongly in favour of aggressive edits (especially on high-voted answers on old popular questions), but even I agree that would be better as a new answer, and shouldn't have been a *suggested* edit.  Especially with trending sort, a couple new upvotes could pop it up to the top for now.

Comment: the 2nd edit did not change the intent at all, it just added the explanation of what the code did to a user who might be tempted to otherwise see commentless code and cut and paste it unthinkingly. Nobody wants that. The original answer was incomplete, the edit made it a good answer.  What's concerning though is the power trip the mods are on (again) banning someone for being helpful is never acceptable, never. You only ban people who are actively detrimental in objective ways.

Comment: @gbjbaanb We are probably not seeing the same edit. It was portrayed by the editor themselves as an update to incorporate new information which could well have been made into an independent answer.

Comment: @gbjbaanb Maybe also drop the assumptions of moderators being ill intended, as the moderator in question [already explained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420322/what-was-wrong-with-this-suggested-edit-which-added-an-explanation-for-the-code/420360?noredirect=1#comment926746_420322) that the decision was founded on the previously established community consensus. It was only after the edit had been brought up here that the unhelpfulness of this edit was contested. Once we're clear on how to handle these cases moving forward, moderators can also lift suspensions accordingly.

Comment: "... this question already shows a heavy sentiment against how this edit was reviewed" -- perhaps, but actually that wasn't my intent. I can't speak for anyone who voted on my answer, but it was motivated primarily by the review suspension, not the edit decision. Specifically: was the OP's action compatible with the instructions given? It's clear that both 'accept' and 'reject' could be interpreted as valid, depending on which instructions you follow and how you interpret them. At that point the edit review resembles a democratic vote, where neither choice should be treated as inadmissible.

Answer (score -7):

If an answer just drops a chunk of code with no comments and the code is not self-explanatory, then it's a bad answer. The correct action then is to down vote.

(These kind of answers actually get showed into the low quality review queue automatically, though most of the time they shouldn't be deleted since they are just bad but attempt to answer the question.)

The edit was correctly rejected/rolled back because the changes were too radical and may change the meaning of what the original author intended - you were essentially writing a whole new better answer inside someone else's mediocre answer.

What you should probably have done instead of editing was to post a competing answer but with a much more detailed explanation.

Comment: I don't really agree, why do we insist on not going against a non-existing intent? If the author didn't post an explanation there's no concrete intent an explanation edited in can go against. The only way we can conflict with the authors intent is if the explanation is incorrect in which case we can simply reject or rollback. Also in this case the edit was probably by the same person (see comments above) and they just lost access to their posted answer to be able to edit it. (Although I agree that reviewers don't need to investigate that part)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat If the OP provided no explanation, so you should assume their intent was not to add an explanation. Adding such an explanation goes against their intent. The proper behaviour is to add a new answer. The fact that - maybe - this OP created two accounts does not change this, because we can't know for sure.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Speculating about the intent of someone posting a code-only answer isn't meaningful and far beyond our expectations on edit reviewers. Also this isn't wikipedia; we can't just do radical changes to someone else's post unless that post was converted to a "community wiki" which isn't the case here.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I would reply by quoting [Cody Gray's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416114/should-i-explain-other-peoples-code-only-answers/420326#comment926360_420326): "_No author ever intends to post a low-quality answer, and even if they do intend this, I'm perfectly happy with our being inconsistent with that intent._" (The question which that comment is on should really be where we are discussing this)

Comment: @Lundin "_Speculating about the intent of someone posting a code-only answer isn't meaningful and far beyond our expectations on edit reviewers._" agreed. Then why do we speculate that adding an explanation goes against their intent and factor that into the review? Also "_radical changes to someone else's post_" I thought it was general consensus that once something's been posted on Stack Overflow it belongs to the community.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat You'll have to ask a licence lawyer but I'm fairly certain that every post copyright still belongs to the author. By posting on SO you agree to let SO have infinite free access to your posted material. And then the license allows tweaking that material, to some extent. It might no longer be related to license at that point, but to SO policies.

Comment: @Lundin I am not talking about the copyright of the content, the content and the copyright of the original post obviously belongs to the author. But the community is free to edit it and create derivative works (with citation) since they have licensed it under "CC BY-SA 4.0". In essence the conceptual "post" belongs to the community, with the original content still owned by the author.

Comment: Re *"post a competing answer"*: Perhaps add something about attribution, plagiarism, etc. to your answer? Especially if such an existing answer is 100% copy-pasted. Maybe there are some existing meta questions to point to.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'd rather not change anything in this answer now, since it would seem it doesn't have a community consensus as it stands. I did not expect that, but +12/-11 votes indicate that many don't agree with this, for whatever reason. It's a discussion post, so that's fine, though I'd like to see some more answers if people actually have different opinions about this.

Comment: Whose or what purpose does writing a new answer serve, that fixing the old answer does not?

Comment: @Sneftel The person who could be bothered to write a complete, good answer and not just dump some code-only answer on the site? The good answer gets credit, the bad, low-effort answer can be down-voted. That's how we set quality standards for the site. Otherwise people might just post any slop and hope that someone else will come and fix it...

Comment: @Lundin Posting slop and hoping someone will fix it is clearly not a dependably winning strategy on SO, to the extent that I don't see it as being important to consider or discourage as a strategy.  Blocking someone from edits just because they ran the *risk* of unworthily rewarding someone strikes me as cutting off the nose to spite the face.

Comment: @Sneftel With that logic we should also start filling out the blanks in any unclear, low-quality question and edit it in a way we personally think makes sense. "Maybe they meant this" guesswork edits.

Comment: @Lundin If you feel like it, sure, though I'm not sure where you're getting the "should" from. Generally I would find it easier to write a good answer from scratch, than to rehab a poor one. But your slippery slope there doesn't sound particularly unpleasant at the bottom.

Comment: I think it becomes more clear if you flip it upside down. If you make major edits to an existing answer you also risk making it worse and then all of a sudden the original author sees more reputation loss from downvotes than they deserve. Edits should be touch ups, not rewrites. Unless it is a community wiki of course as mentioned, then there is more leeway.

Comment: @Gimby the original answerer is notified of the edit and can always immediately and unilaterally roll back the edit if they like. I’ve seen many answers hugely improved by significant edits; I’ve rarely if  ever seen them hugely (or durably) harmed by them.

Comment: ...and *man*, the score on this answer is sloshing around a *lot*. I wonder what one can infer about the attitudes of people in different time zones from that.... right now the Silicon Valley bros are waking up so we'll see how they feel :-D

Comment: @Sneftel just because they can, does not imply they should have to. There are millions of people using this site, I'd be pretty miffed if I would have to constantly revert edits done to answers I've written because it is allowed to majorly rewrite them. Luckily it isn't, hopefully that is why your two eyes among this monster of ours haven't seen too much misery caused by editing.

Comment: @Gimby Then it sounds like the problem you pointed out is a hypothetical one, predicated on patterns of activity far different from those we've both observed. Let's concentrate on the actual situation.

Comment: "Otherwise people might just post any slop and hope that someone else will come and fix it" **This is a good thing**, as long as a) it isn't NAA; b) it's close enough to correct that an edit is easier than starting over; c) the question merits an answer.

Comment: @Gimby Makes a good point. It happens somewhat frequently that someone with good intentions decide to edit a post but they either don't catch why the OP wrote it in a certain way on purpose, or they simply make the post worse, especially when have less domain knowledge than the OP. And it is much harder to guess the intent of the OP of a code-only answer, then the intent of an OP who wrote a proper, fleshed-out one.