# Should suggested edits which add comments to code be accepted?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-edit

I just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35831187) suggested edit. It's confusing to me as I don't know how to review it, so I skipped it. But, I would like to know how it should be reviewed.

Good point (in favor of accepting it):

- No radical or meaning changes
- Adds comments in the code to explain it (and not the code by itself)
- Makes the answer better

Bad point (in favor of rejecting it):

- Changes the code not from OP
- Not 'so much' improvement

I see that someone else voted for rejecting it with the "Attempt to reply" reason. I understand this person, but I don't know if it's the right choice.

For me, as it doesn't change the core or functionality of the code but only adds comments, it should not be categorized as a reply. Also, the edit doesn't add something new, it's only explaining.

What do you think about it?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with that edit; adding context to code to explain what it does is the difference between an answer and a *great* answer. Certainly the rejection based on that it's an attempt to reply is wrong; the user is in no way attempting to reply to the answer. I'm not an SME in the related tag(s) though, so maybe they have some (odd) rules about comments in code(?).

Comment: "*Changing the code not from OP*" not really a huge issue. It's adding comments. "*Not 'so much' improvement*" seems like a clear improvement. With little else to change. There certainly aren't glaring omissions. I don't see a real reason to reject here.

Comment: I'll argue that while edits like that can provide value, this particular edit does not. It doesn't add anything of value to the code that isn't easily understandable from the code already, making it a pointless edit

Comment: I searched for something about comments in code, but I didn't found anything. And as it's the code, from what I read, changing directly the code of OP is not allowed as it can conflict/be a reply. That's why I post it: it's in the code, but it's the code itself

Comment: "*hanging directly the code of OP is not allowed*" it's to be *avoided* if possible. It's not outright banned. If it was the repository of knowledge we're building would be *very poor*, since we'd be forced to keep every single minor and easily fixable typo. Instead of fixing in the cases it is abundantly clear that it's not what the author meant.

Comment: If I reviewed the post-edit code, I'd suggest removing the comments because they just repeat what the code does. It's not like it's so complex that it needs prose to explain. So, in my opinion, this doesn't improve the answer.

Comment: Repeating what others have said, the comments just describe what the subsequent line is already clearly doing, these are nothing comments and are totally unhelpful. Rejected as no improvement.

Comment: I think the comments are a textbook example on what to avoid when commenting, describing what the code does instead of why it does so. As it doesn't add anything but noise I would have voted to reject as well.

Comment: Related: [Should I explain other people's code-only answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416114)

Comment: "Makes the answer better" No, makes it worse, adds noise.

Comment: I would have approved that Edit. The current Answer is just a 3-line Code Block, with no explanation..., oh yeah...!, there is some explanation, => 3 Links to follow, that should qualify this Answer as a 'Link-only-Answer'...!

Comment: The usefulness of comments is to some extent in the eye of the beholder.  What is "obvious" (to whom?) or "easily understandable" (by whom?) to the experienced developer may be much less so to the beginner.  It becomes a question of what level of experience is to be expected for each answer in StackOverflow.

Comment: @Technophile, yep indeed, exactly how I feel, even if I tried to withdraw my UV on your Comment (but I was apparently too late (60sec)), as I don't really understand what a "_beholder_" is..., ... and hum, why they only have 1 eye...!? Care to explain both...? (Need to reboot btw..., ping me if you reply, or I might lose the Tab...)

Comment: Definitely not. All experience shows that comments in code are not read here. For example, sometimes people put their actual question in the code as comments. They are invariably asked to state their question in prose outside the code. In any case the only person who should author comments is the author of the code.

Comment: @chivracq It's a common phrase: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-eye-of-the-beholder

Comment: @user207421  That is not evidence for comments not being read.  That is evidence of the (to me, very reasonable) expectation that the person asking a question -- asking volunteers to help them -- put in the work to clearly state what they want, and to do that in an expected location, rather than leaving every person reading a posting to hunt through it and put in work to puzzle out what the question was.  Also, sometimes doing the work of clarifying a question brings an answer to mind.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Always ask yourself whether an edit actually *improves* a post. Merely adding fluff is not an improvement.

> **The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary** or make the post more confusing.

This specific edit is pointless. It's the classic beginner comment style repeating what the code already shows:

```
# assign the value to x
x = value
```

Instead, useful comments should explain *how* some intricate code works or *why* a seemingly arbitrary action is taken. For example, a useful comment might say *why* `cache.Set` is used instead of `cache.CreateEntry`.

Comment: pointless, yes, for you. But for some people such comment may be valuable information. The example is, of course, exagerated, because an explanatory comment on a more complex statement may be of real usage for a lot of colleague developers, while there may be experienced guru's that find it just boring. I would advocate for a cost-benefit analysis. What is the cost of storing an extra line of ASCII bytes, plus the cost of annoying some guru's, compared to the value as perceived by the expected colleague tasked with maintaining that code.

Comment: I agree with @Roland. One must remember that generally speaking, the person asking the question is less experienced than the person answering it.  That means what may be perfectly obvious to the answerer may be the missing link to the asker.  I wouldn't advocate writing production code this way, but if it is an explanation to a specific question, and particularly if it is only 3 lines long, "adding noise" really isn't a concern. Making sure the asker fully understands each individual step, no matter his/her experience level, is the main concern.

Comment: @Roland: Some conventions are so widespread in programming (like that `=` is assignment to the left-hand side) that code really can be self-explanatory even to people who don't know the library or much about that particular language.  The example in this answer is case where someone just needs to read a beginner tutorial for the language if they don't already see that.  Those comments aren't going to teach anyone how C# works, and shouldn't attempt to be a tutorial for people who don't know the language.  (Having written a heavily commented asm hello world answer, there's a *lot* of detail...)

Comment: (continued...) The comments in the linked edit review are so generic that they're already clear from context; it's the details like the `out result` by-reference output parameter that total beginners to C# might not know, or might miss at a glance.  So a possibly useful comment could be `// result is a reference to the object if the bool return value is true`, else it's ??? I don't know because that answer *doesn't* have a useful comment.  (Roland and @David)

Answer (score 2):

Let me add some more depth to the discussion, as I'm the author of the edit suggestion.

The code comments are not really the clue of this edit, but rather the line breaks.

What I wanted to emphasize with my edit, is that these 3 (non-consecutive) lines of code should be placed in 3 different places:

- the first one which initializes the cache — usually in the constructor;
- the second one where the cached is checked — usually before getting the actual value;
- the last one where the value is put into cache — usually after getting the value.

So you see that there clearly needs to be something in between those 3 lines, as when put as a single block, this code does nothing in particular.

Maybe I failed to convey it in the comments, but at the same time, I wanted to avoid being too elaborate to avoid too much noise, though I can now see that I'm accused of it anyway.

Now that I'm thinking of it, maybe a better edit would be not to comment the lines themselves, but the space in between:

```
IMemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
bool found = cache.TryGetValue("Key", out result);
    
// if it's not found in the cache, get the value from the actual source here
    
object result = cache.Set("Key", new object());
```

Although it would require changing the order of the lines in code.

Comment: If what you intended to show was that those lines of code are to be used in different places it should not be code comments that do that but instead paragraphs. Generally though it might be difficult for such edits to get approved and might be better to do with edit privileges. Here's an example of how I might have structured that: "_First you need to initialize the cache like so: ...., Next if you want to add something to the cache you can use the `Set` method like: ...., to get a value from the cache you can use `TryGetValue` like: ..._"