# Is this Q&A about finding the time complexity of any (!) algorithm good enough to act as a general duplicate target?

Tags: discussion

The Q&A [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm) is mentioned relatively often in related Q&As. I don't think it does a good-enough job in teaching the ability of finding the time complexity of an algorithm.

[The question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11032015/12323248) is broad – it should be actually closed for lacking focus IMO – and asks about how one can calculate the time complexity of any (!) algorithm. This is difficult to answer properly and formally correct in the Stack Overflow format.

[The first-placed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11032063/12323248) does not attempt to answer the question. It does not teach any methodology on how to calculate time complexity. It just takes the simplistic example in the question and explains why `2` is ignored in `2N + 2`. Then it "explains" why also the factor `2` is ignored in `2N`. However, the latter explanation is straight-up incorrect. It has nothing to do with tradition, nor has it anything to do with if `2N` is well-defined. This property – "constant factors are dropped" – is derived from the mathematical definition of Big O.

[The second-placed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14396503/12323248) also does not attempt to teach any methodology on how to calculate time complexity. The whole answer is basically a simplistic explanation of what Big O is. The given examples are supposed to show some complexity classes, however, the explanations on why each given algorithm has a specific complexity class are very sparse.

[The thrid-placed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22688792/12323248) is more or less the same thing as the second-placed answer, just in worse. Again no attempt to teach methodology on how to calculate time complexity. The difference is that it skips examples for a quadratic and logarithmic algorithm. I'm actively ignoring the linked algorithms because I think it's lazy to just link some Wikipedia articles. This should not be the standard for Stack Overflow.

[The fourth-placed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33474486/12323248) is partially a worse version of the second- and the third-placed answer. But, it has at least an example of the analysis of an algorithm at the end. It's not a great example and not explained well and detailed, however, it's at least a step in the right direction to answer the question, which is about methodo..., I stop.

There is no proper answer under this question IMO. I think most users who post questions about time complexity ask about simple algorithms. Most often these algorithms are either constant, linear or polynomial. "Calculating" these complexity classes is usually intuitive. I often see explanations like "Yoy, that's two nested loops, that's O(n^2)!" and that's fine; no formal calculation is *needed* in most cases. A reference like the Q&A I'm talking about here, which summarizes some basic concepts, is good enough ..

.. but is it when it comes to more complex algorithms? I strongly doubt that any reader of this Q&A will be able to calculate the time complexity of more complex algorithms, ones that belong to logarithmic, factorial, exponential and other complexity classes. I strongly doubt that any reader of this Q&A will be able to handle recursive algorithms; they would need to find [Determining complexity for recursive functions (Big O notation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation) at least.

To make my post here a little more constructive: What is the best way to handle this Q&A? Is there any need for a change at all? Posting a new answer *is* an option but not an *ideal* option IMO, as the accepted answer would stay the same.

Comment: If the existing answers are deficient, posting a new one sounds like the obvious approach. Over time it may overtake the existing ones.

Comment: I'm not quite following what exactly it is you are complaining about. Why do you feel there is anything that would need "handling"? What *specifically* are you asking of people? Do you expect the accepted answer to be un-accepted? Do you just dislike the Q&A – but why more than any other? If you don't feel the content is sufficient, downvote and/or add a new answer. Same as for any other Q&A.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm asking what we can and should do so that this Q&A actually provides what its title promises. I think this Q&A is a perfect example of outdated and bad content that has aggregated upvotes over the years while being quite low quality actually. When we look at the content closely, it just scratches the surface. If someone's question is closed with this being the target, I'm sure that it won't help often enough. I'm just somewhat interested in how much Meta is interested in curation of this site beyond the daily business and how such cases should be handled. Is that clearer?

Comment: Afraid not. Handling outdated content has been discussed to death on meta. There's the [outdated answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project). So is your goal *active curation* of that specific question? Is your goal to find out whether Meta is interested in that question? Is your goal to discuss outdated content in general? Is your goal to get people to stop using it as a dupe? Basically it's not clear to me whether the question just serves as an example, and if not then what you expect to happen.

Comment: FWIW, I disagree with your interpretation of answer quality.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think everything I've posted here, including the title and the comment, perfectly explain my topic and what I want from this Meta post. The Q&A is not an example, *it is my topic*. I've *reasoned* why I think the Q&A is low quality. Great, you disagree, but maybe you should *reason why* you disagree instead of dropping a one line comment and feeling constructive with that.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm aware of the other Meta post, however, I dislike how broad and abstract it is. I thought myself that posting about a specific case and discussing how to improve it is a constructive and practical thing, more so than endless discussions about the general case in some comment sections on Meta. Apparently, most people disagree and downvote. Why? I have no clue and it feels bad.

Comment: Look, I am trying to answer – which is why I am trying to find out *what* to answer. So far this question raises the issues of: The Q&A is not suitable as a dupe target. The Q&A is not *teaching* how to calculate complexity. The question is too broad and should be closed. The answers focus on simple cases (which the MetaQ acknowledges as being the most common). The answers only offer sparse explanations. Some answers refer to Wikipedia, which "should not be the standard for Stack Overflow". A hypothetical reader would not find complexity for some cases after reading the Q&A. Which to reply to?

Comment: To put it more abstractly: This meta-Q just comes across as a huge block of complaints. At least to me, these complaints seem to be statements of fact – they do not invite discussion, one can only agree or disagree that they are true. All of this is framed in the context of duplicate closure but does not actually address any such case. For a Q&A that is almost a decade old (thus being held to different standards) and apparently being positively received (thus being good enough for many), it just comes across as a rant.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The points you've mentioned are just different aspects of why this Q&A is problematic and requires improvement, at least in my opinion. I think the scope of this Meta post is perfectly fine. To answer your question: All of it! Every aspect is part of the problem and needs to be considered when searching for a good solution. The problem is that this Q&A is actually not teaching how to calculate time complexity, not even really for simple cases, but it is used as a duplicate target for that purpose.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I can see the point that my post here might seem like a rant. I was actually worried about this when I've posted it, especially because one *has to* open the Q&A and read the answers carefully to actually see that they are problematic. Someone who just visits the Q&A and sees only the voting probably thinks that I'm talking nonsense here. Anyways, after I've read my post again, I've decided that it's fine. I'm describing the deficits in the answers in a neutral way. If I'm wrong, then this is what discussion is for. I'm really not ranting or trying to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235298/discussion-between-mistermiyagi-and-akuzminykh).

Comment: *"It has nothing to do with tradition, nor has it anything to do with if 2N is well-defined. This property – "constant factors are dropped" – is derived from the mathematical definition of Big O."* Is "tradition" not the reason we use big O notation in this context, rather than something a bit stricter?

Comment: "Posting a new answer is an option but not an ideal option IMO, as the accepted answer would stay the same" - true but that shouldn't be much of a problem. The accepted answer is just a flag, not a magic spell that when you look at it everything else goes complete dark and turns invisible. There are of course people that look no further, but those people will eventually hurt themselves enough that they will change their ways; give them time. Don't use a (bad) accepted answer as an argument against dupe linking. People who know what's good for them read all answers that look relevant to them.

Answer (score 6):

There are many books written about time complexity of algorithms. It's pretty much the definition of a "too broad" question. Even if you limit the scope to a "recursive functions" or "graph traverse algorithms" - still, you can write books on the subject. Too broad.

---

If you have a gold badge on a tag, and you want to close a too broad question quickly, close it as a duplicate of this too broad one.

`</tongue-in-cheek>`

Comment: which too broad?

Comment: I honestly don't see this criteria working. There are many books written on *lots* of things people ask about here. "No, you can't ask about JS, there are books written about it." Are they all too broad just because there are books out there?

Comment: Yes, pretty much exactly that. The purpose of this site is providing answers of no more than a few pages (there is a limit somewhere about 30 K), but often much smaller (a few lines of text). If you want to ask a question with a very long answer (like "How do I do JS programming properly?"), better read a book - this site has wrong format for that.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I think the point is that a proper answer (to a very broad question) would take up an entire book.