# Duplicate questions with deprecated answers

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

Recently I noticed that questions are far more aggressively being closed as duplicates than a few years ago, with the linked questions often being only tangentially related to the closed (alleged) duplicate. While this might or might not be an issue (are there new user incentives for closing questions?), I've seen this problem arise in some circumstances:

Questions, mostly regarding constantly-evolving web technologies, are closed and linked to duplicate questions with accepted, then-valid but now-outdated, answers.
Especially with CSS we have far more possibilities and solutions in 2021 than we had in 2016. This means we get questions that could today easily be solved using flexbox, columns or css-grid closed and linked to old questions with answers stating that this is not possible in CSS, or offering long deprecated solutions.

How should/could this be handled? Is there an option to appeal the closing of a question that I am missing or don't yet have permissions for?

Comment: Maybe post a new answer on the old question. The answers should be centralised on one question so they can be compared and ranked.

Comment: Merging may some times be an option when there's a new and an old question, though this is for obvious reasons not an option if the goal is to solicit new answers to an old problem. There's other systems for that though, like bounties.

Comment: "*(are there new user incentives for closing questions?)*" there aren't. But the same questions are re-asked again and again. We want a single place for all the answers, not a catalogue of "here is how you'd do this in 2019, here it is in 2020, here it is 2021", etc. Especially since the old responses still work. And in some cases, there isn't anything better. If there *is*, then that's the job of [the Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302) to promote newer more relevant answers.

Comment: Instead of asking the same question again there is already a nice mechanism to draw attention to existing questions that need up-to-date answers: Bounty!

Comment: Related: from the 2021-07-21 blog post *[The Loop: Our Community & Public Platform Roadmap for Q3 2021](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/07/29/the-loop-our-community-public-platform-roadmap-for-q3-2021/)* (my emphasis): *"We will also be exploring the concept of a Trending sort that* ***weights recent votes more heavily*** *than older votes."*. [Corresponding MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368049/mse-feedback-post-feedback-on-q3-2021-community-and-public-platform-roadmap).

Answer (score 9):

The solution is simple: Scroll to the very bottom of the old questions and read **all** the answers

I close questions all the day using dupe target that are 10 years old and this is fine because they contain outdated and up-to-date answers but the issue is people that stick to the accepted answers or the most upvoted one when there is more than 20 answers.

I do this in the CSS tag and many old questions are still valid today and will remain in the future. I myself add new answers to such questions.

Remember that the model is question/answer**s** (I insist on the **s**) and not question/answer

Comment: "but the issue is people that stick to the accepted answers or the most upvoted one when there is more than 20 answers" - that might be a design/onboarding issue. I can understand why newbies or non-users coming to the site might understand the green checkmark of an accepted answer to mean "this is the best solution" and not "this is the solution OP deemed as best at the time of writing".

Comment: @RenéRoth it's not a design issue. when you go to the shop and the seller show you his best article you will not buy it automatically if you see there are more articles in there. Newbies are (sorry for that) *lazy* because even without the green checkmark they don't take the time to read the answers, they simply want to get a fast solution while the real solution is to spend a good hour reading, testing, understanding and then picking the right solution. Sometimes the solution is within the comment section of an answer (someone adding an improvement to an answer in the comments)

Comment: maybe that's more of a philosophical question then, how much handholding should be done to aid beginners, and what our responsibility towards them is. I could think of a few ways in which conditional messages (old answers, first-time visitors etc) could help fresh learners, but that's probably a wholly different discussion :)

Comment: No; Hand holding shouldn’t be done; We can only present the information it’s up to them to read it

Comment: Do you link to the relevant ***answers*** in comments so they get more attention?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I do when I have in mind a particular answer that should be considered but not when I know that many of the answers apply.

Comment: @RenéRoth in my opinion that green checkmark lies as it makes it seem like that thing speaks for us all, but it speaks for only one person. A bit of flair text which says "<OP username> considers this answer the most useful" would be far closer to the truth and you have to be really trying hard to misinterpret that. It doesn't really matter if laziness is in play here... regardless that thing is a misleading eyesore. But it isn't going anywhere.

Comment: @SecurityHound honest and good-faith question: Why not? Is there a mission statement of SO that'll make it easier for us to reach an objective consensus on what amount of "handholding" should be strived for?

Comment: @Gimby [my favourite take on the green checkmark](https://www.monkeyuser.com/2020/election/)