# Should I update my question to use present tense?

Tags: discussion

About two years ago, I asked this question: [Will consteval functions allow template parameters dependent on function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130792/will-consteval-functions-allow-template-parameters-dependent-on-function-argumen)

This question is related to [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20) which was not published yet at that time, so using the future tense felt natural to me. 
Now that C++20 is published, using the future tense seems a bit weird, but is it a valid reason to update the question (and bring it back to the front page)?

Also, should I avoid using future tense in my questions, even if it is related to an upcoming feature?

Comment: I, personally, don't think it really matters. The tense was correct at the time, and editting it doesn't really feel worth while in my opinion.

Comment: I kind of wonder if the question should have been asked to begin with as what is the long term usefulness of it? It seems like a product of impatience. All you had to do was wait for C++20 to be released to the public in some form and then you would have been able to try it out. Did getting educated guesswork prematurely help you in some way, besides take the burning sensation out of your curiosity?

Comment: Well, if I had waited, I think I might have asked a slightly different question instead ("why is it not allowed" instead of "is it allowed"). But except for that, I think you're right actually. Answers about not-yet-released features are likely to quickly become obsolete, and probably should be avoided. So I take this as answer to my second question: don't ask questions about upcoming features at all.

Comment: I'm curious what the general feeling is on future questions - many sites on this network specifically disallow them as it's generally difficult (or impossible) to know what the future releases of something will contain, so any questions will be 1. difficult to answer without insider information (or some public release or beta) and 2. will be low-value questions once the release is out since the answer may often be obvious - e.g. On Movies & TV - "Will the next [insert series movie] include [insert character]?

Comment: I would suggest context is everything @Catija . Some breaking changes are announced well in advance of a release so that people can prepare, or preview versions are made available prior to actual release, for example. In both of these scenarios I would personally suggest that asking about "how to do this in Future Version *y* of *x*" is on-topic, even it it can't be tested in a release environment. For your example of "Will this be available in a future version of *x*." these would likely be guesses at best, and so would be off-topic.

Comment: Just answer a simple question, does changing the tense of the question, make it easier to understand and/or easier to find?

Comment: The reason I asked, if changing the tense would make the question easier to understand and/or find, the question is already answered.  It does not appear the answer would change by updating the tense, so I would argue, changing the tense would unnecessarily put a 3 year old question on the front page.  I don't see a reason to edit a question unless it's unnecessary to make it easier to find.  The question is properly tagged and titled, how easy it can be found, won't be effected by the tense of the question.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I cannot accept this because, well, it's a comment, but I do agree. I'll just leave this question as it is.

Comment: @Annyo - The reason I didn't submit my comment as an answer is due to the fact, it would simply quote the guidance on editing contributions, and because you already accepted an answer

Comment: @Catija Speaking only for Java questions on SO (and nothing else), your comments about future questions are misstating a few points. First, all planned changes to Java are formally documented and publicly available well in advance of their release through [JDK Enhancement Proposals aka "JEPs"](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0). Second, Java provides beta releases for researching and testing those future changes. Finally, some Java insiders (i.e. those who actually propose and make the changes to Java) regularly post comments and answers on SO.

Comment: Don't be _tensed_ about using different tense.

Comment: Personally, I would never hesitate about editing your own question just because it might cause it to appear on the front page for another 20 seconds. Edit freely.

Comment: @skomisa the thing is that we can be asking about things that may never be implemented or are stalled indefinitely or are iterated several times. That's why in general, it's kinda not recommended to do this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The question you asked in the past was asking for details about the future.

A future question you may ask today about a prototype or beta feature in a language may also use future tense.

I don't see any reason to bother updating the question, since it's widely understood that a question asked is only ever asked in the present tense.

Answer (score 11):

The question has a date. When you find this question and see it was asked 8 years ago, you already know that the answers clearly refer to the state of the topic back 8 years ago, and that the answers might be outdated. The question is not about whether it is possible to do X, rather, about whether X will be possible in a future.

On the other hand, this does not necessarily happen with questions asking for help for a certain programming issue (such as "how can I do X with framework Y"), since updates to the framework or library may outdate the answers, hence why the [Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project) exists.

So, despite the question and its answers are clearly outdated, it is self-evident that they are, and modifying the question will not add any value to somebody searching for that same question.