# Link-only RTM answers: A new call to cull them for being unneeded page bloat?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

After more than a decade of feverish Q&A, is it finally time to start chipping away at the least valuable answers?  Manual-link-only answers are merely acting as traffic routers.  Instead of actually demonstrating the resolving technique, they just point to the manual. They are never the only answer on the page, but they are certainly the least generous.  We don't want RTM comments under the question, so why tolerate them as answers?  Were these posts just the consequence of FGITW posting? ...it doesn't really matter.

I've made a simple SEDE search for manual-link-only answers advising the `explode()` function to PHP-tagged questions.  Here's what I've found:

- 2011: [I think that explode() is enough.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5158844/2943403) (0 score, not accepted)
- 2011: [You can use the explode function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5275609/2943403) (highest score, accepted answer)
- 2011: [You should just use PHP's explode function :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5447706/2943403) (lowest score, accepted answer)
- 2009: [http://php.net/explode edit: damn, Rob was faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1481144/2943403) (+3 score, not accepted)
- 2010: [Check out the explode() function, and use + as your delimiter.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2222944/2943403) (0 score, not accepted; goes above and beyond to advise a delimiter)
- 2010: [You want explode() instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4229448/2943403) (+2 score, accepted answer, tied for lowest score)
- 2011: [You can use the PHP explode() function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8228818/2943403) (0 score, not accepted)
- 2011: [just use the function explode look at http://php.net/explode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485146/2943403) (+4 score, not accepted)
- 2011: [If you "know how to split the string up", then you already know that this process produces an array.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485223/2943403) (0 score, not accepted)
- 2011: [The explode function will get you what you need.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5491127/2943403) (0 score, not accepted)
- 2011: [You are correct. explode is the best function for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5782084/2943403) (-1 score, not accepted)
- 2011: [@Deceze blows away the competition with generosity here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6693763/2943403)
- 2011: [Use the explode() function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6763774/2943403) (0 score, not accepted)
- 2011: [See PHP's explode() function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7382438/2943403) (0 score, not accepted)
- 2011: [Try using explode function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7504108/2943403) (+2 score, accepted answer)
- 2011: [I myself cannot remember the parameters for every function, so just go to the php.net website and search for the explode function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7626551/2943403) (-2 score, not accepted)
- 2012: [You can use http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8963930/2943403) (-3 score, not accepted)
- 2012: [Use explode function to split the string into array.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9125152/2943403) (+1 score, not accepted)
- 2012: [Use explode function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9125168/2943403) (+1 score, not accepted)
- 2012: [use explode with <br>http://php.net/explode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10217872/2943403) (0 score, not accepted; goes above and beyond to advise a delimiter)
- 2012: [You could explode each result using the | as a deliminator.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10807275/2943403) (0 score, not accepted; goes above and beyond to advise a "deliminator" -- which of course natively says "hasta la vista, baby")
- 2012: [Have you tried the explode() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11912316/2943403) (+2 score, not accepted)
- 2013: 
  [You should have a look at explode in the php manual.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14209439/2943403) (0 score, not accepted)
- 2013: [Exploding the value should do the trick: http://php.net/explode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14805330/2943403) (+3 score, not accepted)
- 2013: [Look up the explode() function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16114577/2943403) (+1 score, not accepted)
- 2013: [Use explode(). See the documentation http://de3.php.net/explode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17648046/2943403) (+3 score, accepted)
- 2013: [explode function should help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19920937/2943403) (0 score, not accepted)
- 2014: [See explode function, it will do the job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21188674/2943403) (0 score, not accepted)
- 2014: [you can use exploade function http://in2.php.net/explode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22555018/2943403) (0 score, not accepted)
- 2017: [Use mb_split instead of explode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43184600/2943403) (0 score, not accepted)

Granted the few answer that mention a specific parameter, may just stick their head above the line that I think should be drawn between tolerable and delible content.  ...for now.

Should we:

1. Downvote and delete them?
2. Flag them as NAA as a pathway to deletion? (I know the famous Shog says they are [partial apples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/352329), but aren't they just sending viewers to the manual?)
3. Get moderators to convert them to comments? (but other answers often also have the link to the manual in their fuller answer -- this would just be moving the page bloat elsewhere)
4. Keep them because they are SUUUUUUPER important to the researcher experience. <-- (yes, that's sarcasm.)
5. Nuke the whole lot of duplicate pages!

The SEDE:

```sql
SELECT a.Id as [Post Link], a.CreationDate
FROM Posts a
INNER JOIN posts q ON q.id = a.parentid
WHERE q.tags LIKE '%<##tag?php##>%'
  AND a.PostTypeId = 2
  AND LEN(a.Body) < 150
  AND a.Body LIKE '%php.net%explode%'
ORDER BY a.CreationDate ASC
```

You can very easily find more of the same manual-link-only answers by swapping out `explode` for `trim` or `substr` or `isset` or `implode` or `strstr` or any native function name.  Even `ucfirst` and `array_map` had a manual-link-only answer or two found by my query.

Comment: I see you're already [commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626481), casting [close-votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805321) and even [delete-voting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648006) some of the questions you linked... You might wanna refrain from doing that whilst the discussion is ongoing. Doing so _before_ you submit a Meta question about them seems kinda disingenuous.

Comment: Also, all of those links are over 5 years old... Do you have any _recent_ links?

Comment: I wasn't going to keep thirty tabs open on my work computer for a couple of weeks -- I took actions that I felt were appropriate. Why does age matter at all? I never feel that post age is ever a meaningful factor in content curation.  Quality is quality (or lack thereof), no matter when it was posted. My concern is for the researcher experience.  I almost exclusively necropost because virtually all new questions are close-worthy.

Comment: There are plenty examples of __old__ content being kept around 'cause the rules were different back in the day. That's why I'm asking you for some recent examples to illustrate that this still is a problem. You also don't need to keep 30 tabs open, you have a nicely accessible list on this page :D

Comment: IMO, "'cause the rules were different back then" is not a strong argument for why we shouldn't try to improve all content now.

Comment: Sure, but that still doesn't invalidate my request for you to show is this is an current, ongoing problem.

Comment: It is a current problem because the manual-link answers are currently viewable on Stack Overflow.  Old pages are more important to curate than new pages because they have more traction with search engines and are used to close new pages.

Comment: You're linking to questions that have less than 1k views, generally. Many of them are below 100 views. I think you're overestimating this "traction". And if you don't want to include some recent examples, at least give us the SEDE query so we can look into this ourselves.

Comment: you will find that most of the old questions and answer don't meet current standard, so why not let bygones be bygones

Comment: @nbk if much of the old content does not meet the current standard, then what is the harm in trashing the worst of old content so that only the best content remains for the world to see?

Comment: @mickmackusa   i sometimes encounter "old" posts that are still valid till today and can be adapted to modern languages, the basics are all still valid. So my point of view is, they don't harm, doesn't bither no one and qas long as the databases can hold it let them be, maybe someone will find an usual answer. And in schools they teach really old stuuf like fortran freebasic and hooro java till today.

Comment: @nbk in every single instance that I provided, there will be no page value lost by culling these RTM answers.

Comment: @mickmackusa you can't know from every person who stumbles on StackOverflow what he is searching for or even what he needs to proceed, if you are all knowing, on what people want , give me your private number and i will come back to you(this is of course ajoke)

Answer (score 18):

Looking at the first 10 from your list (and assuming the list continues the trend), those aren't strictly link-only answers.

Those are answers that tell the OP what function to use, accompanied with a link to the function's documentation. Sure, they're not awesomely good answers, but they are answers.
If the link's target sites were to go "poof", those answers still answer the questions.

So, to answer your points:

1. We don't delete answers just because they're not particularly *good*. You could downvote them, if you think they're bad enough.
2. NAA doesn't apply at all. [They're answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer).
3. That's a bunch of manual effort for what?
4. They're not that important, nor are they that harmful.
5. See point 1.

If anything, these duplicate questions need to be closed as such. The (existing, ***old***) answers aren't the problem.

---

So, now that we finally have the [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1569972?tag=php), I ran it, showing the newest sorted answers first.

Out of the ***millions upon millions*** of answers SO has,

## 37 `explode` answers qualify for deletion according to the OP.

The newest answer it returns was posted 2017-04-03. ***5 years*** ago.

Suffice to say this discussion illustrates a non-issue and is a massive waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I know that they don't meet the current definition of NAA, but they are ALWAYS the least generous answer on the page and often these same "hints" are posted as comments under the question BECAUSE they are just hints.

Comment: @mickmackusa There's no "but" to "they're not NAA"... They are, or they aren't. NAA doesn't apply to these answers.

Comment: Well, the definition of NAA _can_ change if the community decides that it is for the betterment of the community to raise the bar.

Comment: But that's not what this question is about. This isn't a [FR]/[Discussion] to change what NAA means, so we're using NAA as it is now.

Comment: Let's use this "discussion" page to appreciate that link-only answers that include a function name are always the lowest value answers on any page (excluding incorrect answers).

Comment: "Worst" doesn't necessarily mean "bad", so your whole _"lowest value"_ argument really doesn't mean anything.

Comment: On every single page that I referenced,  if the link-only /no-implementation answer went "poof", there would be absolutely zero value lost.

Comment: So that justified deleting a user’s contribution? No. It doesn’t.

Answer (score 7):

They are definitely answers. Even though it's only a link, it actually tries to answer the question. Flagging as NAA is inappropriate and such flags will be declined.

They might seem low-value, and many probably are. But to many beginners, just knowing the name of the function is a lot of help. Of course, we rely on the community to rate content based on how useful it is to them. You can do so too, just downvote if you think the answer is low-value and upvote if you think it helps.

1.

> Downvote and delete them?

See above. You can downvote based on your own personal judgement and I can't tell you what you should do here. If the answer has negative score, you can vote to delete, but make sure that doing so won't lose any value. Even bad suggestions can be valuable if we see that they have low score.

2.

> Flag them as NAA as a pathway to deletion? (I know the famous Shog says they are [partial apples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/352329), but aren't they just sending viewers to the manual?)

No! They are answers and such flags will be declined.

3.

> Get moderators to convert them to comments? (but other answers often also have the link to the manual in their fuller answer -- this would just be moving the page bloat elsewhere)

No! They are answers, not comments. Moderators will only convert actual comments into comments.

4.

> Keep them because they are SUUUUUUPER important to the researcher experience. <-- (yes, that's sarcasm.)

Yes. They might not be super valuable, but they don't seem to be harmful either. If you don't find them valueable, you can cast your downvote.

5.

> Nuke the whole lot of duplicate pages!

This is a valid solution for many of these questions. We don't need to keep many duplicates of the same problem, especially if the duplicate is not easily searchable (has low view count) or the information on the duplicate is presented in a less than useful way.
I prefer to keep duplicates that have a clear problem statement and good title. If the answers are on-topic then there's no reason to delete them.

It's commendable that you want to help new researchers find useful information quicker, but make sure that what you are doing actually helps find the information quicker instead of making it more difficult. Even if the answer only suggests a name of the function, it is a step in the right direction. Usually, what wastes time during research are poorly written questions. They attract views despite not having useful information in answers or even misleading problem statements. Such questions can be deleted, provided an edit wouldn't salvage them.

If a question can be answered with just a link to a function in the documentation, it is most likely a common duplicate.

Comment: Even knowing the right search terms can be very useful (especially for readers who may be very confused).

Comment: If these manual-link-only answers are adding searchability to the page, then I can easily assume that the users are searching for "explode" or "php.net" -- in which case, they will never benefit from finding the link-only answer.  If the answers contained valuable keywords like "split", "break up", "divide", or other such synonyms, then I could appreciate the searchability argument.

Comment: Or they're searching for keywords in the question, and end up using the answer. @mickmackusa, the problem here is that you have to prove that keeping those answers around has a _negative_ impact on the site. Not that they're of limited value.

Comment: On a page where there is a manual-link-only answer and at least one other answer that actually provides an implementation of the function call, the link-only answer can be safely removed.  Stack Overflow does not want to be a hyperlink storage place.  It is common to see the better answer also containing a link to the manual, but the link to the manual is less important if there is an actual implementation. Unnecessary answers cause page bloat and unwanted scrolling.  I am talking about improving curation, not maintaining the status quo.

Comment: If researchers are finding keywords in the question, then they can find the solution that is actually implementing the function call on the page.  The link-only hint could have been posted as a comment, because it doesn't actually offer a solution.  We don't need answers to link to php.net.  The php tag description already links to php.net.

Comment: Again: _"you have to prove that keeping those answers around has a negative impact on the site."_

Comment: Negative impacts: 1. Unnecessary page bloat 2. Bad role modeling of what a good quality answer looks like 3. Users are gaining language tag points for their expertise despite only dropping a hyperlink and suggesting a function name.

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with many of the examples supplied. If you strip the markup, many of these are still answers and thus should not be flagged or deleted. For example:

> explode does not do Regexen. preg_split does.

Even this still provides an answer:

> See PHP's explode() function.

Those are not long answers, but even after I strip the link off they still provide *something* to go off of; if readers want more information, there are clear search terms to use. These answers are very much like the canonical examples of things that *are*, in fact, answers in the [official guidance on NAA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

The fact that many of these answers are similar suggests that some of the questions *may* be dupes, but I lack the domain knowledge to know that for sure since I don't know PHP well. However, even in that case, dupes aren't inherently bad, especially if some of them use different search terms (because then it makes it easier for future readers to find the information), so this doesn't necessarily prove that we should delete all of them as horrible monstrosities that shouldn't exist.

Comment: My opinion is that `See PHP's explode() function` does not provide a solution -- it directs a user to a place that they can go to learn how to devise their own solution.  It doesn't give an actual solution, it is saying "Ride your bike to the local library and find the book called "Explode with PHP".  I was less calling out Deceze's answer abour Regexen; I was indirectly pointing out the other "answers".  Answers that merely mention a function name are not solutions, they are hints -- at the MOST they are "half-answers".

Comment: That may be your _opinion_, but clearly SO's rules disagree. You can keep insisting on said opinion, but that doesn't change how SO works.

Comment: @mickmackusa It may not be a great answer, but it still provides at least *some* information for the OP to go on.

Comment: And they are ALWAYS the least helpful/generous answer on the page.  My point is less about the definition of "what is an answer?", and more about "why bother keeping the lowest quality answers that do not bother to show an actual implemented solution?". No user will wonder which function to use or how to use it because the function call is actually demonstrated in another answer AND simply linking to php.net is done by the php question tag.  There's nothing worth saving about these lazy/minimalist answers. SO can raise the bar, there is no rule against improving content.

Comment: @mickmackusa If you think the answer isn't useful, you're perfectly free to downvote. I don't think that it's correct to call them link-only, though, because they provide useful information even without the link. I personally think that the answers could be useful (because if you're really lost knowing what to search for can still help a lot), but you are, of course, free to vote either way.

Comment: @mickmackusa The fact that several of these have positive scores, or are even accepted, seems to support my argument that even having search terms or a function name can be helpful (even if it's pretty minimal as an answer).

Comment: I have seen way too many bad and even incorrect answer with upvotes and green ticks.  These are not trustworthy metrics for what is truly valuable to researchers on SO.  We don't require any provable knowledge or understanding of positive curation before awarding the privilege of upvoting.  This is likely the consequence of overly generous upvoters (commonly whom have encountered a FGITW post). No one will be able to convince my that upvotes assures quality/worth to SO.  I mean, come on, the reason we unpinned the green tick is because the OP cannot be trusted to identify quality.