# How does the trending sort algorithm apply to this question?

Tags: discussion, sorting

In reference to [trending sort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416486/an-a-b-test-has-gone-live-for-a-trending-sort-option-for-answers), how do these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66480618/bash-how-to-read-tab-separated-line-with-empty-colums-from-file-into-array) implement the sort algorithm? Since both answers are from the same day, it seems unlikely that the "You can split..." answer (currently 1 upvote) to be sorted above the "With IFS="anyWithespaceCharacter" read there is..." answer (currently 6 upvotes), which is how they are sorted now...

I guess this sorting is possible if one of the "stronger" decay functions are being used...is there a way to see which decay function is being applied? How should we provide feedback that this particular decay value is too aggressive?

[image]

Comment: For these answers, the last upvote on the 1 scoring answer was on Feb 11 2022, the last upvote on the 6 scoring answer was Nov 11 2021 and 4/6 votes are from the day it was posted Mar 4 2021 (over a year ago). Which is why there is such a disparity. There have been a few requests for more transparency of the algorithm ([here](/a/417513/15497888) and [here](/a/417592/15497888)). The extreme effect this algorithm has also been noted [here](/a/417585/15497888) with several example questions listed.