# Why does sort by Trending appear to favour recent downvotes over older upvotes?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-review, downvotes, sorting

I was reading through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275994/whats-the-best-way-to-do-a-backwards-loop-in-c-c-c) with *"sorted by:"* set to *Trending*, and noticed something curious towards the bottom of the page; an answer with [fairly negative feedback (-5)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276084/12220191) was floating above [several (+4)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276146/12220191) [positively (+4)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276001/12220191) [received (+3)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276793/12220191) [ones (+1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/369137/12220191) in addition to a similar number of further answers with either no feedback or fewer negative responses. Investigating, I checked the dates of these interactions to find that while almost all of these answers had been given around the same time (in late 2008), only the answer with a score of -5 had received a vote more recently than 2015, having been voted on **negatively** in both 2016 and 2021.

At present then, it appears that **all recent votes have a positive effect on post visibility under *Trending*, rather than just recent positive feedback**. And sure, while it *is* true that this negatively rated answer has been interacted with more recently, and *"recent votes count more"*, I can't help but feel this is not the intended behaviour of the *Trending* sort function. **In fact, shouldn't more recent negative votes actually have a greater negative effect on a post's ranking than older negative votes (and at the very least have a non-positive effect)?**

Comment: So this is explicitly a bug then? -An answer with only negative interactions in the past 5 years *should* always be shown below any answer with no interactions in the past 5 years according to the linked page.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ maybe. I just happened to look at the negative vote interaction today. And few hours later you asked about this, so I posted the relevant information. I can't actually see the trending sort, so I can't even verify what is sorted where.

Comment: For me "Trending sort" shows the answer far behind several upvoted ones, but still before some positively scored answers (at +4, +4, +3, answered in 2008).

Comment: Confirming that this is a bug, answers with no recent votes are set to `Int32.MinValue` when they should really be set to 0. I'm unsure on if we'll fix it mid test, but we will have this fixed for the implementation we release