# Why didn't upvoting an answer make it appear above another answer with a single upvote with trending sort?

Tags: support, answers, sorting

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/816619/10352740) with "Sort by" set to "Trending" and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64534980/10352740) useful, so I upvoted it. After looking back at the other answers, I just realised [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57265731/10352740) was displayed above the one I just upvoted.

According to what I read from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416486/10352740), trending score wise, the single upvote on the other answer can't account more than the one I just gave and in case of a tie (because the other upvote on the question I upvoted would be decayed to 0) the 2 "normal" score would beat the 1 "normal" score.

How come the other answer with score 1 (+1/-0) is displayed above the answer I just upvoted that has a score of 2 (+2/-0) and an upvote from today (mine)?

Comment: The question you link announcing the test specifically says that the sort is heavily cached.

Comment: Ah I understand, it says decay score so I thought it wouldn't include my new vote since it wouldn't be decaying yet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the announcement post under "How will the test work?":

> One technical limitation of the test is that the decay scores will be cached aggressively for 24-36 hours. If you vote after viewing the page, you won't see an immediate change in the Trending sort order of the questions until the cached values expire and new decay scores are calculated. We don't expect this limitation to be there when we ship it.