# Trending: A new answer sorting option

Tags: discussion, answers, sorting, outdated-answer

**Update 2022-08-09:** New votes now update Trending scores immediately instead of waiting for the cache to expire

As part of the [Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project), we ran [an experiment to try and surface trending answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416486/3023052). On June 21, we are launching a new sorting option on Stack Overflow called Trending sort. Trending sort will enable you to see the most relevant answers by boosting recent votes. If there's no recent votes, it will sort by Score instead. This sorting method will be especially helpful for questions on programming languages like JavaScript that are constantly changing and receive newer and more efficient answers. However, Trending sort will be less effective with questions on languages like C that are relatively stable. There are no changes to the default sorting method of Score.

### Launch details

Trending sort will be available starting on June 21. During the launch, the first time you view any question sorted by Score on Stack Overflow, you'll be prompted to try out Trending sort. If there are any answers with more recent votes, Trending tries to sort them closer to the top. Once you dismiss the popover, you won't be prompted again.

[image: A modal is shown near the Highest score sort option. It introduces Trending as a new option that boosts votes that have happened recently to help surface more up-to-date answers. It also says that Trending is based off the highest score search and falls back to using score when no posts are trending. The modal has the option to try out Trending sort.]

Trending is an optional sort method that complements the default Score sort. Trending works best when there are recent votes on answers that aren't the highest-scoring answer. We often see this happen when software adds or removes features. Questions with Trending answers look like [setting the distance between flexbox items in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626685/better-way-to-set-distance-between-flexbox-items) or [finding the sum of an array of numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers) because browsers and their features have changed over time. However, [how to undo your most recent commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git) hasn't fundamentally changed over time, and the top Trending sort answer is the same as the highest Score sort answer. You'll get to choose to use Trending as your sort option wherever it makes sense to you.

The algorithm we chose was the best performing algorithm in all aspects of our experiment. It positively impacted how users copied and voted on answers. It also ranked best in our subjective survey. You can see the full results of our [test to choose the best candidate Trending algorithm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416486/a-b-testing-of-a-trending-sort-option-for-answers) in [Results of the Trending sort experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418766/results-of-the-trending-sort-experiment).

### Implementation details

An upvote or downvote's value under this algorithm decays to half of its value each year. The Trending score of an individual post is calculated with something like the following code:

```cs
/* an example implementation */
var trendingScore = 0.0;
foreach(Vote v in post.Votes){
    trendingScore += v.Weight * Math.Pow(
        1.0 / 2.0, 
        vote.AgeInDays / 365.0
    );
}
return trendingScore;
```

We won't calculate Trending scores on questions younger than three months as we don't expect there to be enough voting data. If a question is too new, Score will be used instead of Trending.

Before July 28th, Trending scores were cached for 24 to 48 hours, so they may have seemed a day or two stale in some cases. Now, new votes will immediately update the Trending score on the next refresh.

In our initial implementation of Trending scores, we have not exposed the specific score in the interface, our public API, or the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. The score shown on each post when using Trending score is just the standard Score. Eventually, we would like to visualize Trending scores in a more accessible way, but we haven't made commitments to anything specific yet.

We know that sometimes you'll see a newer answer with a small number of votes rank higher than established answers under Trending sort. We are not guaranteeing that Trending will always find the best answer, but it will find the answer with the most recent voting. Using similar metrics to our [test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416486/a-b-testing-of-a-trending-sort-option-for-answers), we will monitor the performance of Trending sort and make adjustments if necessary.

### Feedback

We would like to hear your feedback in these locations:

- If you see any bugs or errors:

  - In the first few weeks after our launch, we would like to collect bug reports as answers to this post.
  - After July 11, please submit a separate question with the tags [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [sorting](/questions/tagged/sorting)
- If you'd like to comment on the specific algorithm choice or our survey results, please join the discussion on [Results of the Trending sort experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418766/results-of-the-trending-sort-experiment).
- If you would like to suggest a feature for Trending sort, please submit a separate question with the tags [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [sorting](/questions/tagged/sorting)

Comment: As far as feature announcements go, this is one of the most clear and well written announcements from SO that I remember in a while. Kudos.

Comment: 21 June can't get here soon enough!  This is going to directly improve the ability of content curators to combat bad/misleading/unwanted/incorrect content that has increased its score due to the snowballing effect of upvoters' bias toward top ranked answers.  By reducing the chance of uninformed voters upvoting bad content, curators will have an easier time downvoting bad content so that it qualifies for deletion.

Comment: Trending: implementing trending features.

Comment: Is this planned to be released on the rest of the network too?

Comment: @Laurel we don't have immediate plans to bring it to the rest of the network, but I think that there's value for having it on some sites. We want to evaluate its performance on Stack Overflow during the first few months before we consider it on other network sites.

Comment: This didn't end up going out today due to a bug - we will try again tomorrow!

Comment: We're slowly rolling this out today. If you're logged in, we've silently added Trending as a option and you can already start using Trending. We'll soft-launch it to all users in a couple hours. Tomorrow, we'll turn on the modal advertising the new option and feature this post.

Comment: This is great, thank you for this feature! More stuff like this, please (stuff we have been asking for for years, that is) :-)

Comment: I thought that both buttons "Try it" or "Dismiss" would permanently remove the "Trending sort available" indicator. Currently none removes the indicator. How am I able to remove it? I got the information, thanks, but now stop bugging me.

Comment: It would be nice if the Trending Sort ~~tooltip~~ popover linked to this thread so we didn't all have to Google it!  980 views in 7 days sounds like not many people are seeing this post relative to how many have the option to try trending sort (presumably all SO users).

Comment: @RandRandom it should stay dismissed, if you can't dismiss it it's a bug. I think we store that information in a functional cookie. Would you be able to write up your bug as an answer to this announcement so we can track/fix it?

Comment: This is a good example of how changes should be made. Opt-in, not changing something where it takes a lot of effort for people to restore original functionality/design.

Comment: Can we get other options too, like showing the answers that I've upvoted first, and showing the accepted answer first?

Comment: This does not seem to work, unfortunately. Multiple times with trending sort active, I have visited questions with old, 1-score or 2-score answers (who have been that score for > 1 year) that appear above newer answers, and when I upvote the newer answer and refresh the page, the ordering is the same. How is trending sort *supposed* to work in these cases? I would expect it to always see the new vote and say "rank this higher than any answers of the same score who were upvoted in the past by at least `n` weeks/months/years" or something. At this point I can't discern *any* effect from it.

Comment: @TylerH Caching. It only updates the sort every 48 hours or so.

Comment: @TylerH the problem with caching should be fixed as of July 28th and I've updated this post to reflect that. If you're still seeing stale Trending scores please let us know and also link the question/answer you're seeing the problem on. Would be strange if a single upvote today doesn't beat an old single upvote.

Comment: Thanks @Catija and Kyle; I haven't checked since July (I tried it a lot before August). I will give it another go soon.

Answer (score 37):

There's some awkward wording in the modal shown in your screenshot. In addition to the wording being awkward, I would suggest not using the word "surface" in this context. While it does mean what you're intending, I'd expect it to be less understandable to users who don't have as high a proficiency in English.

###### Current screenshot:

> You can now choose to sort by **Trending**, which boosts votes that have happened recently, helping to surface more up-to-date answers.
>
> Trending is based off of the highest score sort and falls back to it if no posts are trending.

###### Recommendation 1:

To say nearly the same things, I'd suggest the following (with repeating the "Trending" name an additional time to help people remember):

> **Trending** sort is now available for sorting answers. Trending sort gives more importance to recent votes, helping to increase the visibility of answers which may be more up-to-date.
>
> Trending sort is based on the highest score sort and falls back to it if no posts are trending.

###### Recommendation 2:

Alternately, the following is closer to the structure you're currently using:

> You can now choose to sort answers by **Trending**, which boosts recent votes, helping to increase the visibility of answers which may be more up-to-date.
>
> Trending sort is based on the highest score sort and falls back to it if no posts are trending.

Comment: I prefer #1, I think it reads better.

Comment: [From the Stack Overflow "design system"](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/principles/): *"Write for a 7th grade reading level"*

Comment: I do not like how #1 reads; starting all three sentences with "Trending sort" sounds very clunky to me. I'd prefer #2 or the original wording.

Comment: @zcoop98 #1 is a bit clunky wrt. "Trending sort", but intentionally so. The intent was to repeat the name of the new feature, such that it's more likely to be remembered after reading the popup (which I *assume* is shown only once). Personally, I strongly dislike the original wording. As for #2, it's really a compromise, but retains some of the things which I consider poor about the original wording (e.g. burying "Trending" in the middle of the first sentence, such that bold is *required* to call attention to it; a more complex sentence structure, which will be harder for users to parse; etc.)

Comment: I greatly prefer #2 over #1. I think #1 is rough because it feels almost like it's a new feature available when writing answers ("Trending sort is now available for answers"), especially if you've never taken notice of the sort options. I also dislike how you start all three sentences with "Trending sort". It's just bad writing (which you say is intentional, but  there's no reason for it). The only thing I don't like about the original wording is "which boosts votes that have happened recently". There's already more than enough "trending" in various places around the popup, we don't need more.

Comment: @Clonkex Thanks for pointing out that #1 sounded like trending sort might be for while composing answers. I've updated it to be a bit more clear. Starting each sentence with "Trending sort" is something which I would actively avoid, if this was some other piece of writing. In a popup, which is being shown to the user once in order to introduce the feature, my opinion is that the desire to make the feature stick in the user's mind is more important than the issue of repeating the name at the start of three sentences.

Comment: Repetition is one of the major methods available to facilitate the user remembering the name of the sort and that it is available. If this was something that was going to be shown to the user multiple times, I'd strongly argue against using it so heavily. Perhaps my understanding of how that popup is intended to be used is incorrect.

Answer (score 34):

Just a small thing, but "Trending is ***based off of*** the highest score sort" is painful to look at to me.

[It seems that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15081/based-on-instead-of-based-off-of) it's somewhat common in American English, but it still doesn't make any sense. In the words of [someone smarter than me](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/based-around/):

> You can build a structure around a center, but bases go on the bottom of things, so you can’t base something *around* something else.
>
> Similarly, you can build something off of a starting point, but you can’t base anything *off of* anything. Something is always based *on* something else.

Comment: *sigh* (the unchanged popup, not you). Yeah, the "based off of" was one of the things I found annoying enough to motivate me to take the time to make suggested changes. Maybe I should have gone through and detailed the why for each individual change.

Comment: A more formal way would be to say "based on" (or "based upon"). "based off of" is slang and shouldn't be used in the verbiage of the site.

Comment: *[base off of](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/base_off_of#Verb)*: *"1. (US, informal) To base on."*

Comment: So…you're saying that the current wording is *off base*?

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, and maybe *(US, informal) on base* ?

Answer (score 24):

It seems recently downvoted answers are being shown before unvoted answers with Trending sort. For example, on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63387098/discord-py-how-to-make-the-bot-send-a-message-at-a-specific-time-to-execute-a-co), a now-deleted answer with a negative score was shown before the accepted answer with no votes.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps because as per the timeline of that answer it got an upvote on 1st of June. Although this does bring up a point that maybe recent downvotes should also count more in lowering the sort rank.

Comment: That would be exactly right - this is a limitation with caching called out in the "Implementation details" section of the announcement. Someone visited the post when it had a score of +1, it got cached, and then two downvotes happened after. The cache hangs around for a couple days. We have plans to fix this limitation.

Comment: This limitation should be gone as of July 28th, votes should update the Trending score on the next refresh.

Answer (score 21):

> You can now choose to sort by Trending, which boosts votes that have
> happened recently, **helping to surface more up-to-date answers.**

The last part of that sentence is extremely misleading as it implies that those answers have some feature which they don't necessarily have. You don't know those answers are more up-to-date, more relevant, or anything similar.

The only thing you do know is that those answers have been more recently upvoted. Any categorization beyond that fact will be misleading and potentially harmful.

Please remove that part. Or as suggested by Trilarion replace "more up-to-date" with "more recently upvoted".

Comment: I agree that we should not be misleading in our modal and I want to make sure I understand your post. I feel like the text says that Trending helps find relevant answers, but don't feel like it says that they're strictly better. I agree that an answer being newer doesn't imply that it's up-to-date or better. Trending changes the top answer when recent votes are biased to another answer, but tends to sorts the same as Score for answers that are still best. Our survey also found that Score sometimes showed answers that are outdated and Decay-50 tends to sorts new high-quality answers to the top.

Comment: I don't really think that's what it implies at all. I think most people here are capable of knowing that "more up-to-date" != "better".

Comment: Even saying it is up-to-date is not necessarily true. You have plenty new answers to popular old questions that just reiterate what has already been said where the actual technology hasn't changed a bit. When you say "Trending boosts votes that happened recently" then that is stating a fact fact. When you say "helping to surface (whatever)" the this will be misleading no matter what you put in that sentence.

Comment: "it implies that those answers are better" Doesn't have to imply that. Instead of removing just replace "more up-to-date" with "more recently upvoted", which is a neutral description of what happens.

Comment: The trending mode does, in general, allow more up-to-date answers to be sorted first. That’s what all the tests were about. I agree that not all answers put forward are more up-to-date, but that’s not what the modal is saying. It’s saying 1) what it’s doing: boost recent votes, and 2) why: to improve up-to-date answers’ visibility

Comment: @Cimbali there's no logical pathway that links that a recent engagement means that the content is more up-to-date compared to other answers. While that may be the stated goal, it doesn't do anything that mechanically assures it. That's why the language implies that it does something that doesn't do. Yes, it was meant to fix a problem. No, it doesn't do anything to fix said problem.

Comment: @Braiam The logical pathway is obviously that useful answers get upvoted, and top-voted answers that stop receiving upvotes are out of date. I guess you didn’t read the whole series of posts on sorting answers. There’s a lot to catch up on, including why it’s a problem, unpinning, experiments, etc.

Comment: @Cimbali If I had a dime for every old question where someone posted subpar or "me too" answer that was somehow upvoted... this will be heaven for sock puppeteering. Number of questions where more up to date answer will surface more easily is extremely low.  What we really need is ability to version answers and sorting based on versions. Not "Trending" sort.

Comment: "helping to surface more up-to-date answers" does not mean that the answers on top are more up to date. It just says that it helps you to find the answers that are more up to date. Which is true.

Comment: If it were more up-to-date answers, then it should be based on last edit time.

Answer (score 7):

### Improve wording

This is really convoluted, verbose and hard to read:

> Trending sort is based off of the default sorting method — by highest score — but it boosts votes that have happened recently, helping to surface more up-to-date answers.

Suggest:

> Trending sort is based on the highest score, but it boosts recent votes, helping to surface more up-to-date answers.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm seems to perform poorly on old questions. For example, on [Get Absolute URL from Relative path (refactored method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681052/get-absolute-url-from-relative-path-refactored-method) the top two upvoted answers, one of which is the accepted answer, are very far down the page, covered up by answers which are also 5-10 years old and have 3 or fewer (sometimes negative) upvotes.