# Grammatical error in new 'Introducing: Trending sort' info box

Tags: feature-request, grammatical-correction

Upon coming to Stack Overflow for the usual reasons, I noticed the following panel on the top answer:

[image]

In particular, the second paragraph begins as follows:

> Trending is based **off of** the highest score sort...

The emboldened text marks an unfortunately common grammatical error which I wanted to bring to the community's attention; I found that this seems to be the place to do so.

For those who are unaware, this should instead read "...is **based off** the highest..." or "...it **based on** the highest..."

Comment: Already reported [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418882/479156).

Comment: My apologies! Had a brief look, but didn't find this. What should I do about this post?