# When are "This worked in [related or unrelated technology]" type comments worth keeping?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags, no-longer-needed

### Background

Lately, I've been spending a fair amount of time doing comment analysis and have been looking through a few thousand comments a day.

We have quite a few broad categories of comments that come into Stack Overflow. Naturally, plenty of these comments do not need to be kept on our site for any amount of time. Some of them detract (or obscure) otherwise useful information.

It's well established that [Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer](/help/privileges/comment) and that they should be used to communicate [minor or transient information](/help/privileges/comment) and [[y]ou should not expect them to be around forever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/1099857).

Having said this, we know that [this is not always how they're used](/posts/comments/121649) and there are frequently very useful additions to questions and answers that live in the comments.

When flagging comments as no longer needed the [help center](/help/flagging) (and the flag text) sets the following guide:

> no longer needed - the comment is obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary

We have a fairly well established policy of removing "thanks" and "you're welcome" type comments, so much so that there are [certain heuristics that make [these] types of comments a bit, shall we say, *easier* to flag away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99853/1099857).

### Situation

There's a subset of these "thank you" and "worked for me" comments which contain a *tiny* nugget of additional information which *may* be useful. These comments are the "thanks this works for me in [related or unrelated technology]"

A few real life examples:

- "Works in [similar technology]"

  - [Fine also in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/66914224)
  - [Works in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/97818952)
  - [Works fine in Sublime as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/108878865)
  - [android studio too](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/109148734)
  - [Works in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/118007074)
  - [Likewise in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/122221139)
  - [Works in Anypoint Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/126170945)
  - [Works in RStudio as well, many thanks!](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/128925960)
  - [This also helped me connect to Postgres via PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/71683589)
  - [Works for PyCharm as well](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/93824831)
- "Works on [browser]"/ "Works in [version]" / "Works in [year]"

  - [Works on: IDEA 2020.3.4 + eslint 8.19.0](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/128925990)
  - [Thanks @Aubricus, that worked for me on python 2.7 :-)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/99631490)
  - [still working on 2022 :) saved my day too.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/128928985)
  - [Works as of 2018!](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/87993295)
  - [still working in january 2021, swagger 3.38.0](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/115949034)
  - [save the life.Works fine with chrome and firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/110432060)
  - [Just for completion: 0.01px works in latest Chrome 102 and Firefox 102 on macOS.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/128929378)

### Question

My question is: **are there ever situations where these are useful and should be kept?** and if so:

- under what circumstances should these comments be kept?
- what value does keeping them offer?

if not:

- why are these comments "otherwise unnecessary"?
- is it worth preserving the information in another way like [putting it in the question or answer](/a/277658/15497888)?

---

Note: I am aware there is nuance here and also that some of these are easier to handle than others [Works as of 2018!](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/87993295) is *clearly* obsolete. However, many of these are neither "obsolete" nor "chatty," so if they should be removed they need to fall in the "otherwise unnecessary" category, which I hope to get some consensus/feedback on.

Comment: Honestly -1 from me, I actually didn't understand the QT: "*Are "This worked in [related or unrelated technology]" type comments ever worth keeping?*" // Why do you care about Comments,,,!!?? // If I don't understand the Qt, I usually downvote,and move on... And I will will delete this Comment tomorrow... (Or when I check the Thread again...)

Comment: IMO they're really useful sometimes. The last example you show (about `0.01px`) is valuable for me - I'd never use 0.01 after reading first comments to that answer, but may give it a try with this addition (if ancient browsers compat is not crucial).

Comment: @rene Perhaps a comment rating system via CAPTCHA instead? https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/constructive.png

Comment: For the IDE example the solution is closing the question and have a separate Q&A on each IDE tag that also explains where the setting is and how to change it (chances being each tag already has its own Q&A for it). It's not much use searching for keyboard shortcuts unless they're specific to the tool you're using.

Comment: *It's well established that Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer and that they should not be used to communicate meaningful information.* I know this wasn't the question, but I can say that I had never heard that statement, and I don't accept it at all.

Comment: The temporary Post-It notes is a direct quote from the [linked help center article](/help/privileges/comment). The second part of that sentence may be a bit broad in that a lot of the information communicated is _meaningful_ but that same document stresses that these comments should be focused on "minor" or "transient" information and everything focuses around improving the _post_ and not about the comments themselves. But you are correct, if you'd like to update the help center and the way that Stack Exchange views comments on the whole that’s be a different conversation @SteveSummit

Comment: @chivracq "*If I don't understand the Qt, I usually downvote,and move on...*" That's a pretty flagrant misuse of downvotes, FYI.

Comment: @TylerH Pretty sure the downvote tooltip has "It is unclear" as one of the reasons for downvoting. I mean, it's one thing to go into a tag you know nothing about and start downvoting all the questions, but downvoting a question because it's incomprehensible? That's one of the main reasons for downvoting. Certainly not "flagrant misuse"...

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes, I saw the link, thanks.  I shouldn't have made it about me.  In fact I don't get the impression that *anybody* treats comments as strictly temporary, or not for communicating meaningful information.  I don't believe the Help Center article reflects current practice.  (But I'm not nearly political enough to want to try to get it updated, sorry.)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Good point, although it has its limits.  It's a hallmark of people who don't understand something — and who are therefore asking questions about it — that they *don't necessarily understand it well enough to ask clearly about it*.  I regularly see posters being hectored to clarify their questions — sometimes even being told that their question is incomprehensible and unanswerable — when it's perfectly obvious to me what the OP is asking about.  (Sometimes it's even a race to get an answer composed before the trigger-happy downvoters close the question.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Downvotes don't close questions :P. And if it's perfectly obvious to you, your time might be better spent editing the question than answering it...

Comment: @TylerH, I don't want to start a "Discussion", but "we" are all free to vote the way we want, at least I explained why I had downvoted, I don't see why [Downvote + Explanation] = "*pretty flagrant misuse of downvotes*". // Anyway, OP improved their Title and I retracted my Downvote (and even upvoted)...

Comment: @HereticMonkey There's a difference between "this question is unclear" and "I don't understand the question", and one ought to be able to discern between the two if they are casting downvotes on questions for such reasons. There can sometimes be overlap, which is fine, but there _is_ an important difference. I don't understand most C++ questions that I come across, because I don't know C++. That doesn't mean I'm downvoting every C++ question I see, though.

Comment: @TylerH Right, which is almost exactly what I said in my comment. My point was that downvoting a question because the question is incomprehensible is a perfectly valid way to use one's downvotes, and not a "flagrant misuse of downvotes", as you described it in the comment immediately preceding mine. If only you could have used the same kind of analysis and discussion in that original comment, rather than accusations of malfeasance, a good portion of this comment thread would have been unnecessary.

Answer (score 17):

I think these comments should be removed, but we need to make a distinction between the two forms: "**still** works in (year|version)" and "works **also** in (browser|IDE)", whereas the distinction is based on the nature of the thing in brackets. If it concerns time, or if it concerns tools.

Comments in the form *"still works in (year|version)"* are effectively noise, on the same level as "thank you" comments. Someone with enough rep to comment, has also enough rep to upvote. The upvote adequately conveys to future readers that the answer is (still) good, assuming that there is no practical, tangible difference between something that is good and something that is still good.

<sup>Unless it became temporarily not-good in between, but I digress.</sup>

This is literally what the upvote is for, so additional comments that explain the vote seem redundant.

Moreover, you have to try out the answer eventually, so having a comment that confirms whether it still works or not is of little use; you'd find out soon enough anyway.

---

On the other hand, comments in the form "works also in (browser|IDE)" do convey additional information that isn't immediately discernible from the post. If you are a hard-line curator, you might be tempted to flag those as NLN for the mere fact that "the question asks about VSCode, what does IntelliJ have to do with anything...?!?!". In theory, that is a valid objection, but the next step to not lose potentially useful information is then to find a similar Q&A about IntelliJ and upvote it, or create one and self-answer it. However this probably just never happens, so overall I believe it's more productive to preserve that partially related information.

Posting an answer might step too decisively into the realm of NAAs, so in this case, the comments could be promoted into the answer like:

> This solution is known to work also in: [list of IDEs]

And only then flag the comments away.

One could frown at this because it introduces an unrelated remark into the answer but I think this is ultimately better than just keeping the comments. Comments are inconspicuous, even more so when there's many of them, and when unchecked, the list could simply grow forever for each possible version, year, browser, where the answer "also" works. The comment posters think to do something helpful, but in the end they achieve the opposite and reduce accessibility to the information by diluting it.

When that information is inside the answer instead, it's visible and can be maintained and curated by anyone.

Comment: If an answer says: "This will be removed in future release" - meaning don't use it, then "still works in (year|version)" can be valuable.

Comment: In that case I’d say the answer is outdated and should be downvoted or *errata*’ed to reflect the actual state of things

Comment: Comments do appear in search engine results so there may be some benefit in adding the new keywords to the page does attract new users to the page (re: "also works in [other technology]". Which is one of the reasons for making this question. OTOH I've seen valid technical criticism/tips that are buried among 30 of these comments which is the primary issue with comments that are NLN in general.

Comment: The existing moderation mechanisms can sometimes make these things tricky as well... I _could_ move the comment into the answer: but what is my responsibility there? Do I need to test to make sure it does, indeed, work in that technology or version? What about users without full editing privileges? Would a "also works in x technology adding to the list" type suggested edit be approved? should it? (not necessarily asking for answers here just some things I'm considering with the add to post content suggestions)

Comment: @HenryEcker I don’t think there’s a responsibility issue. If a comment that is candidate for being edited into the answer has a lot of upvotes (with no other contradictory comment) it already has been vetted.

Comment: _"The upvote adequately conveys to future readers that the answer is (still) good"_ I disagree. There are plenty of answers with dozens of votes that become obsolete or broken as time goes on, and the vote count will not reflect that. _Yes_, people can downvote the answer, but it will never have as much downvotes as it once had upvotes.

Comment: @MMM Well, it costs rep to downvote an answer, but not to upvote :).

Comment: @MMM And that's exactly what the [recently introduced trending sort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418767) is for!

Comment: @zcoop98 If only that sort actually worked...

Comment: In general, we have to be **very** careful when deleting content. A *small comment* in 10 words can save you 5 hours of trial and errors (it already did for me along the years of stack-overflowing). This is often not visible when doing moderation because you are not necessarily in the same very precise situation. IMHO: there is enough low-quality questions to spend time on, that it's probably not interesting to remove comments here are there which might be very valuable.

Answer (score 12):

In my past experience, sometimes a *small* comment that looks like rather unrelated when looked at from a far-distance perspective (OP):

> I [...] have been looking through a few thousand comments a day.

can in fact sometimes save hours of trials and error when you encounter the same problem as the question.

I don't have an example ready to share, but if I find one, I'll edit to include it here. In my memories, such an example is: you spend hours failing to compile a library, you find a question/answer about it for compiler X/platform Y which is not the same as the one you use. Then you are happy to find a comment someone left about compiler Z/platform P, which is exactly your situation!

I personally find that most comments cited by OP **have value** indeed for the readers.

Example situation:

- you are a Sublime Text user. You search "Keyboard shortcut to untab" on Google
- you arrive on [Keyboard shortcut to "untab" (move a block of code to the left) in eclipse / aptana?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052772/keyboard-shortcut-to-untab-move-a-block-of-code-to-the-left-in-eclipse-apt)
- you see the answer is written about Visual Studio, oh no... I'll need to post a new question...
- oh ho! good news, someone left a comment about Sublime: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052772/keyboard-shortcut-to-untab-move-a-block-of-code-to-the-left-in-eclipse-apt/1052774#comment108878865_1052774)
- problem solved!

If you remove this comment as suggested by OP, this knowledge is lost.

Comment: To clarify, the reason I asked this question is _because_ I felt that these comments could potentially have value. Considering them just blanket "works for me" and removing them all is not the answer. The removal-leaning stance in the question comes from the fact that _most_ of the comments that fit into this category _are_ indisputably obsolete. Most of the examples I chose to highlight were the ones where an argument could be made for keeping. Which is what I was looking for input on so thank you for providing some (re: the Sublime Text comment).

Comment: Having said this, I'm not sure I fully agree with this argument in this specific case. In that, when the page is loaded most of these comments are not show only [a small subset are shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUJ4o.png). I'm not sure I'm fully convinced that someone who missed "In Visual Studio __and most other half decent IDEs__" (emphasis mine) and "I would think and hope that the IDEs you mention support this as well." would click the "Show 7 more comments" to see the sublime specific comment before either clicking away or just trying it in their editor.

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes I always click on *"Show 7 more comments"*, it sometimes shows a comment that really helps debugging in some cases, that's why I now have the habit to always click "Show more comments" :)

Comment: I understand that you are looking through the comments, and that is probably true of a lot of the people who are here on meta. The sample bias here is, however, that the people who are interacting on meta are probably also similarly familiar with the site features. My statement was that I'm not sure how useful these are to the majority of people who look at the site. Many (most?) of whom are anonymous users who only interact casually with the site. (I know statistics about show more comment click-though isn't something anyone on meta can give, but just something I'm thinking about)

Answer (score 6):

Such comments need to be upvoted.

Often, when I test the sql code of a user, it works, in for example MySQL 8.0.13 but not in 8.0.12, so I tell the user in a comment update your system.

The same goes for GUIs. One can do what the user wants, the other not, independent of the version number.

The same goes for DLLs, addone, nuget packages ...

This isn't worth an answer, but fits perfectly with a comment.

Comment: Why not add the information to the answer instead?

Comment: because there are sometimes workarounds that answer the question.

Comment: I also tend to be a proponent of adding the version used into the answer. That said, that becomes somewhat unscalable over time. Especially when very old answers are still working. The nuance here is still what I was hoping to get some clarity on. _When_ are these comments helpful to keep? Once OP knows they need to update are the comments worth keeping for future readers who may run into a similar problem? etc.

Comment: Somewhat related feature proposal here: [Version labels for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370640/1099857)

Comment: Comments like "*this only works since [date] where the feature/bugfix was introduced in version [x.y.z]*" or "*this only worked until [date] when the deprecated feature was removed*" are indeed useful (and should ideally be part of the answer). However, the OP here is asking about "*this still works today*"/"*this hasn't stopped working*" comments, which are just noise.

Comment: "This still works today" can also be useful. When I see an answer that is several years old and the comment is recent then I am more convinced that trying to implement the approach given in the answer is a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers on this question, I think if a comment is useful enough, it's worth editing into the answer.

For example "this only works on Firefox version X and above" is likely (depending on the context of the question and answer) to be useful to a large number of people reading the answer. As you note, comments are ephemeral and they're second-class content.

If a comment improves an answer, I think it should be edited into the answer.

Comment: I tend to agree with this statement in an optimal sense. It is also inline with [the guidance here](/a/277658/15497888). I still have the related concerns (as I've mentioned a few times now) of moving comments into posts particularly when it comes to suggested edits.

Answer (score 3):

These comments are absolutely useful.

If someone posts an XSLT problem that gets an error, and I try it in my own XSLT processor and it works, then I can't answer the question, but it's a data point that helps someone else resolve the problem, so it's worth recording and the only way to record it is as a comment such as "Your code produces the expected result with SaxonJ 11.3". If the question eventually gets an answer then it's possible the answer will make the comment redundant, but it's probably more common that it doesn't - a lot of answers simply say "change X to Y" without actually explaining what was wrong or why it failed, so the extra information will be useful to someone else who finds they have a similar problem.

Frankly I'm a little shocked that you even consider removing these comments. They can represent the result of a significant amount of work, and I don't like having the results of my work removed by moderators on a whim.

I'm also surprised by your assertion that "comments should not be used to communicate meaningful information". If you have spent some time investigating a problem, but haven't found the answer, it seems entirely reasonable to capture what you discovered during your investigation in a comment, so it's available to others who are also searching for an answer. That comment might well list configurations in which the problem does or doesn't occur; or it might be an account of experiments you conducted which failed to provide the answer -- which it is useful to capture so that others don't have to repeat the work.

Similarly, if a question has already been answered, comments may be useful to qualify or clarify the answer. It may be useful to point out that the solution only works on Linux and not on Windows - even if the OP explicitly wanted a Linux solution, the information that it doesn't work on Windows will be useful to someone else whose search lands on this page.

Comment: Are you saying all of these comments are "absolutely useful"? Including the "Works in 2018!", "Still works Apr 2019", "Works for me (June 20219)" group? Should all 3 of these be kept if they're all under the same post? (Which is a fairly common occurrence, usually once there's one of these comments there become more)

Comment: I can't parse this sentence "How else are you supposed to share the result of your investigation of the problem if the investigation didn't solve the problem?" at least in the context of this discussion. None of these comments deal with when things did not work nor when there are additional information needed to use the solution.

Comment: Nearly all these example comments provide information that might be useful to someone. I can't see that any purpose is served by removing them. Sorry you're having trouble with my subordinate clauses, here's a paraphrase: If you've spent some time investigating the problem, and you haven't come up with an answer, but you've found information that might help someone else to find the answer, or at the very least, to avoid repeating your unproductive line of investigation, then capturing your results in a comment seems the only sensible way to proceed.

Comment: Useful or not, they're always subject to the fact that comments are not answers and are subject to deletion without much notice. If the information is important, it should eventually be incorporated in a more permanent form.

Comment: I'm looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246111/ which includes one of the comments you cited. The question was answered and the answer was accepted, and there are five comments all of which clarify the answer by scoping it: they explain that the solution works on a wider range of configurations than the OP was asking about, or that in some circumstances additional steps might be needed to make it work, etc. That's all invaluable information to someone who finds this question by searching, and whose environment is slightly different from that of the OP.

Comment: I agree, comments can be very valuable. That does change what comments are.

Answer (score -8):

I am against hunting down old comments that are not really harmful, but might violate some best practices.

It just creates more work for the moderators, with minimal benefit, since the OP has already been pinged.

If you get annoyed by a new comment on your post that seems useless, then by all means, flag it.

If you see a user that keeps posting such comments despite warnings to the contrary, possibly flag him.

But in general, I say just let them stay.

Comment: FTR I was not advocating "hunting down old comments." Every one of the linked examples was "active" yesterday. By "active" I mean: the corresponding post received at least one new comment whether or not the new comment is still visible. So while the comments have been around some time, they have been interacted with recently. Beyond this I don't understand the argument that this creates more work for moderators. I'm already casting 100 comment flags there is no increase in work for moderators whether I cast my 100 flags on these comments or 100 different flags.

Comment: Then I really don't understand the rest of the points: 1) "If you get annoyed by a new comment on your post that seems useless, then by all means, flag it." - Are you advocating only flagging comments on your own post and only then if you're "annoyed"? That doesn't seem to be a reasonable way to handle comment flags as a general rule. 2) "despite warnings to the contrary" - what warning? who is issuing this warning? How is the pattern being discovered if we're not flagging the comments? 3) "just let them stay" - (as in the question) why? should they always be kept? what value do they offer?

Answer (score -14):

> are there ever situations where these are useful and should be kept?

No.

> why are these comments "otherwise unnecessary"?

They are essentially saying "works for me" with an extra step, which is a subset of "thanks", which is a well-known candidate for being expunged.

> is it worth preserving the information in another way like putting it in the question or answer?

No. They are not relevant to the question that was asked. Off-topic content should be deleted, regardless of whether it appears to be helpful or not.

The argument that these comments are helpful and should thus be preserved by being edited into answers should be disregarded, because it leads to a slippery slope of answers that continually grow to include more and more use cases. That not only detracts from the actual content of said answer, but creates a maintenance burden because every Tom, Dick and Harry will be submitting edits to add Their Particular Use Case, and those edits will almost certainly need to be reviewed.

Comment: I tend to agree wrt. editing into the question or answer. I don't think that solution is very scalable for these particular comments. _Especially_ if the expectation is that you confirm that the comment is actually correct before blindly moving it into the post (which I think this should be the expectation).