# Suggestions for the "Trending sort available (i)" label

Tags: feature-request, sorting

We've got [Trending: A new answer sorting option](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418767/trending-a-new-answer-sorting-option) for a while now, which is being advertised on every question with more than one visible answer like this:

> [image: Trending sort available (i)]

My complaint is particularly about this "Trending sort available (i)" label: because of its color and position, it is kind of very "in your face", messy and distracting, it catches my eye every time I view a question.

Can you like:

1. Show it only on questions where using trending sort would make a difference in the sort order, compared to the default.
2. Show it only once per user (or browser), until the user has tried it once.
3. Show it inline with the "Sorted by:" label, instead of below it, or above the dropdown, or anywhere else, really.
4. Make the text smaller (like the "Reset to default" text that appears when you change the dropdown from the default).
5. Make the text not bright orange, which is universally used as a "warning" color, and this isn't a warning.
6. Or remove it altogether.

Comment: "*Show it only on questions where using trending sort would make a difference in the sort order, compared to the default.*" seems there is some provision for this - if a question has *exactly one* answer, then you do not get the prompt. That does also count deleted answers, though - if there is one non-deleted and one deleted answer, you do see the trending reminder. Well, at least if you're able to see deleted answers - I've not tried it without that privilege.

Comment: Given that SE did make some minor changes after the announcement, but didn't incorporate *any* of the requested changes brought up in answers on the announcement, I'm not optimistic that they will make any changes to this. Fortunately, [they have said: "The indicator will disappear three months after launch (so, roughly at the end of September) either way."](/posts/comments/916560) So, while I'm hopeful they'll do something prior to removing the notice altogether, I expect nothing to happen until it's removed at whatever time they eventually decide to do so.

Comment: @Makyen expecting nothing is my default modus operandi, but it's kinda depressing, isn't it? You sound tired as well.