# Allow best solution to be revoted if a better answer is presented later on

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes as time goes by, the once accepted answer becomes irrelevant because a better solution is posted. If this becomes the case the community should be allowed to vote for a new accepted answer. This should not rely on most upvotes because I have seen non-sense answers and answers that don't fully solve the problem and just provide a work-around.

Comment: i'd rather we just get rid of the accept mark. Or at minimum just change it to be far less cosmetically relevant. "The asker has indicated this answer solved their problem" (in small green text below the answer)

Comment: Most upvoted answer is at the top anyway, nobody (should) really care about which answer has been accepted.

Comment: "*the community should be allowed to vote for a new accepted answer.*" and "*This should not rely on most upvotes*" are at odds with each other. Upvotes are how the community votes on the best answer.

Comment: @scohe001 Yeah, that's because time and popularity is an evil factor in most cases.

Comment: I'll use this as an example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953124/python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

The most upvoted answer provides a workaround. But it's actually not the best because some things like git require Python to be in the Path variable. The accepted answer is a little too general. The second answer is the solution to the problem and future problems.

Answer (score 8):

Accepted doesn't mean "best solution" though. All it means is that it's the solution that helped the asker the most.

Voting is the way we highlight nonsense answers. If you see one, downvote it. If you think an answer is unhelpful, downvote it.

All you need do to find the best answer is look at the scores. If you want to see whether there's a recent answer that is better than old answers you can use the new [trending sort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418767/trending-a-new-answer-sorting-option).

Comment: The most upvoted answer is not always the best answer, though.

Comment: the [wisdom of crowds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wisdom_of_Crowds) suggests that it is generally true though and really that's the best we can do.

Comment: @c0dezer019 I'm not sure what you're asking for here, then. What meaningful distinction would there be between upvotes and voting for a new accepted answer?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I think what OP is suggesting is that users be allowed to vote on which answer should become the new accepted answer... which does rather *sound* like upvotes by another name.

Comment: @F1Krazy That's exactly my point. You're likely to get the same result in most cases, and even when it's different there's no guarantee that it'll be better.