# Is the "trending" sort broken?

Tags: bug, answers, sorting

I stumbled across this question:
[How can I speed up Python's 'unittest' on muticore machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074074/how-to-speedup-python-unittest-on-muticore-machines)

By default, I have the `Trending (recent votes count more)` option enabled to sort the answers.

This is how the answers appeared to me:

[image]
[image]

Why is the ordering like this? Surely the fourth answer should be shown in second place, considering it has 4 upvotes, whereas the middle two answers do not have any?

Comment: The last answer has a recent downvote, and no upvotes in over 6 years.  The other answers do not have any downvotes.  Seems fine to me, or at least not unreasonable.

Comment: @RyanM the two answers in the middle have no upvotes whatsoever. surely 4 upvotes should count more than 0?

Comment: @Paolo in the score sorting, it does. this is the trending sort. Recent votes carry more weight.

Comment: @KevinB so because of one downvote, the fourth answer which has 4 upvotes is being shown after two answers that have none? doesn't seem logical to me

Comment: Correct. Because someone recently indicated that there's something wrong with the answer with 4 upvotes, it's now ranked below the ones that noone has indicated have problems.

Comment: @KevinB right, but at the same time no one indicated that those two new answers are helpful either! whereas 4 people previously did for the last answer

Comment: Imagine a hypothetical scoring algorithm in which 6-year-old upvotes are worth 0.1 each, and a 2-year-old downvote is worth -0.6.  That answer would have a score of -0.1 (because all recent voters think it's bad), while the answers with no votes have a score of 0 (because voters have _not_ expressed an opinion that it's bad)

Comment: @RyanM A single recent downvote should not be worth more than 4 previous upvotes, or at least not this much

Comment: @RyanM if the answer is "that's how the algorithm was designed" then feel free to answer the question. I'm not sure I agree with the logic of it but whatever

Comment: [The announcement post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418767/2821954) mentioned the algorithm: "*An upvote or downvote's value under this algorithm decays to half of its value each year*"

Comment: "*A single recent downvote should not be worth more than 4 previous upvotes*" on the contrary, downvotes should have much more weight. Otherwise merely 3 or more upvotes negate any feedback from downvotes. An answer with actually dangerous advice and vote breakdown of +50 / -24 should be much less visible than showing up as a "good answer".

Comment: The word "trend" would imply that only multiple votes should influence it, but you know. It shouldn't be taken that literally. Much like the use of the word "reputation". A quaint name, has quite little to do with actual reputation. Especially since many reputable tasks on this site don't increase the score. Naming things is hard.

Answer (score 11):

From [Trending: A new answer sorting option](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418767/19123103):

> An upvote or downvote's value under this algorithm decays to half of
> its value each year. The Trending score of an individual post is
> calculated with something like the following code:
>
> ```
> /* an example implementation */   
> var trendingScore = 0.0;
> foreach(Vote v in post.Votes){
>     trendingScore += v.Weight * Math.Pow(
>         1.0 / 2.0, 
>         vote.AgeInDays / 365.0
>     ); 
> } 
> return trendingScore;
> ```

The vote statistics of the post in question looks like:

```
    
Date        Up  Down        
2021-07-24  0   1
2017-12-11  1   0
2017-07-05  1   0
2014-12-11  1   0
2013-09-05  1   0
2013-07-16  1   0
```

If we apply the algorithm, this post’s `trendingScore=-0.26`, so it's ranked lower than the zero-scored answers.

---

From a personal perspective, I think this is exactly how trending sort should work. It’s supposed to amplify recent votes. For example, if a technology changed and an old answer that was extremely useful in the past and had collected many upvotes becomes no longer useful, it's only right that that answer to be ranked lower than other more useful answers. The default sorting offers sorting by scores anyway, so if you wanted to see this answer ranked higher than zero-scored answers, you could choose the Highest score sorting.

Also, if you think this answer should be shown before zero-scored answers, just upvote it and it will be shown before them.

<sup>N.B. I'm not making any comment about the quality of this particular answer. This post is about the general case.</sup>