# Pragmatism vs philosophical purity of the SO design

Tags: feature-request

Several times now I have come across the following scenario...

1. Important but difficult problem gets posted. The problem is difficult because of some fundamental flaw in the operating system or language.
2. There are no easy answers but over the years many tens of thousands of users visit the question and dozens of (complex) answers are put forth with the most popular ones getting hundreds of upvotes. There are also a great many comments added to the original post and the top answers.
3. Many years (10? More?) later a new version of the language or OS is released and the problem almost entirely vanishes. It can be fixed with a single trivial line of code. There is now no argument about how to do it.
4. Someone adds the new answer (and on day 1 it appears at the bottom of the pile of answers with zero upvotes).
5. The number of people that even visit the question is dramatically reduced (but not to zero because some people don't know about the new simple solution) so the new correct answer never rises to the top of the pile (or maybe takes years to do so). In the mean time anyone that visits the question is going to be very badly served by the bewildering array of existing answers and comments.

I know that the philosophy of SO is that good answers rise to the top but in this scenario couldn't a case be made for having an exception to the rule, for example allowing the question to be re-asked? Or allowing moderators to somehow flag a question as having a fundamentally new type of answer.

Or here's an idea - allowing a new question to be asked so long as it clearly contains the following two things:

1. A statements about a new scenario, something like "In light of the latest release of the OS..."
2. A link to the old established question.

You could optionally subject this to some rules about the original question, e.g. it must be greater than a certain age or have greater than a certain number of answers, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't the trending soring option kind of solve that problem?

Comment: Just because a new version is released doesn't mean it is/can be used by everyone! The "new correct" answer simply isn't an answer for everyone and not intrinsically "more correct" than the others. I'm very active in the Python tag and advise everyone to use a recent version (3.9+), but my $DAYJOB still requires me to use Python 3.6 and Python 2 on a massive scale.

Comment: How would the exception actually work? Asking a question for a specific version in which the "new correct" answer becomes possible requires knowing the answer already. Finding it instead of the old question requires knowing the answer already. Or would people just re-ask every question for every major/minor/patch version to be sure?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: re your first comment: I fully agree with every word but I would still suggest that for all those that have the latest version, the fact that there is a trivial one line answer is valuable information that they would hugely appreciate - however this information my be buried near the bottom of a long list of answers/comments.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: re your second comment: How about restricting this to cases where all the following must be satisfied: The original question must be more than 5 years old and must have more than 15 answers and the top answer must have more than 500 upvotes. Also perhaps this should be done by a moderator that discovers (or is told about) both the scenario and its answer.

Comment: @Mick (RE how this could work) I don't see how either of age or score affects whether a new question is appropriate. There is tons of old, important technology that hasn't fundamentally changed in ages. Note that moderators are generally assumed *not* to be subject matter experts, so anything that requires expert knowledge (e.g. knowing there was a fundamental change) is not a decision up to moderators.

Comment: The [outdated answer project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302/7296893) seems relevant. However, I'm not sure if that's still alive

Comment: I tried to delete my very downvoted question but was prevented from doing so because it has an answer. I feel like am now in purgatory, condemned to receive more an more downvotes in perpetuity! Is there anything I can do to withdraw my awful question or at least stop collecting downvotes?

Comment: @Mick downvotes work [differently on meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), they don't affect your reputation either. Downvotes on your question probably simply mean that people disagree with your suggestion.

Comment: You don't receive downvotes! Your post does. That's a huge difference, because you as a person don't need to care about it. You can use it as a lesson for future, but as others commented, on Meta it means disagreement so there's not much to learn from it.

Comment: We need canonical for: "I posted feature-request hence asking for up/down votes to see if feature is supported and you downtrodding elitist did not support my request even if **I** wrote it"...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start a bounty with a message that you would like to reward the new up-to-date answer. Upvote the answer you think is best. This will attract viewers who will also have a chance to upvote the new answer and/or downvote other ones. The new traffic could even attract better alternatives or edits to existing answers. The new answer soon will be at the top of trending view.

Comment: What is this "trending view" - does it exist already? Or is that just something you are proposing?

Comment: @Mick it exists already, see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418766/results-of-the-trending-sort-experiment

Comment: Thanks Abdul, I had never noticed it before. I think they could do with it at SuperUser too.