# Flags for wrong and highly upvoted answers

Tags: feature-request

Meta already had a discussion on this [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers), with a wide range of solutions. Unfortunately, it was a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion), so 8 years later we still have a horribly wrong outdated answer and not-an-answer as two top answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926551/recommended-way-of-making-react-component-div-draggable), and almost two pages of wrong answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111657/how-to-get-names-of-enum-entries). Upvotes there are still ticking. Mentioned questions were picked because SO is doing particularly bad at displaying a go-to answer, and I also cared enough to try at least writing a semi-decent answer there.

The proposed solution, partially based on previous discussion:

1. Extend "not an answer" flag to mean what it actually sounds like: the answer not attempting to answer the question;
2. Put "not an answer" flags into a review queue instead of asking for a moderator attention;
3. Add a flag for "wrong/outdated answer" that works in the same way as "close" vote. Upvotes from novices for an answer being "helpful" shouldn't balance on the scales with downvotes for the fact it being completely wrong;
4. Show a message "this answer is wrong/outdated" on top if it was flagged several times as such.

Comment: Your solution does not clearly relate to the problem.  Is the issue that the answers are wrong, outdated, or not attempting to answer the question?  These are three different problems, with arguably three different solutions.

Comment: You can't nuke most outdated answers. There will still be folks struggling with legacy systems where the answer is still correct. If the answer has become harmful or has been subsequently discovered to be harmful... That is a problem.

Comment: I didn't propose removing outdated/wrong answers, neither did the linked discussion. It's important to at least _mark_ them as such.

Comment: @RyanM I don't understand how I failed to communicate the problem in the description above, but I'll reiterate: there are wrong/outdated/not-an-answers that are upvoted and keep being upvoted. It signifies someone is still using them in their production. Neither their authors nor readers are at wrong here, the problem is that at the moment there is no way to explicitly communicate the answer is wrong.

Comment: *"wrong/outdated/not-an-answers"* these are three _different_ things.  Answers that don't attempt to answer the question asked can be mod-flagged with an explanation of how they don't attempt to answer it.  Answers that are _wrong_ must have attempted to answer the question in order to be wrong ("Tuesdays, unless it's raining" is not a _wrong_ answer to "How to reverse a list in JavaScript?", for instance).  And outdated answers are neither wrong nor non-answers: they're correct, but for a previous version of the system.

Comment: If the answers are wrong, why have you not downvoted them? Subject mater experts (SMEs) downvoting wrong/unhelpful/bad (but not an outdated answer which clearly says to what versions it does/doesn't apply and/or you can edit that in), in addition to upvoting correct/helpful ones, is a critical part of having quality content on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange. [Note: I don't know anything about specifically your votes on those posts, but like all users with > 1k rep, I can see that many/most of those answers have *no downvotes*, so, obviously, you didn't downvote the ones with no downvotes.]

Comment: Relevant: [Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302)

Comment: @Makyen Unfortunately, I'm out of votes for today, but there actually was only one (probably) correct answer. Now we need exactly 1337 more downvotes to get it on top. I couldn't hope for a 13373r proof that current voting system is completely broken.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph you could be wrong too, perhaps the answer was correct *but you only think it is wrong*. Which is why your downvote brings that answer down from 6 to 5. But if the answer really is wrong then **others will agree and also downvote**. It would help if you left a comment explaining why the answer is wrong, so it is easier for others to spot the mistake and vote accordingly. Or, perhaps correct the error. But **you alone** don’t get to have a veto on what is right or wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's why for every answer I provided a comment with a counterexample.

Comment: Downvoting is only pointless if *no one* votes down. Don’t be that guy that doesn’t vote.

Comment: Where are those 1337 people that should have downvoted? Well, yes, it seems _no one votes down_. Don't want to be _that guy_ that uses up my daily vote cap.

Comment: I don't know if it's obvious only to me, but there is no incentive to downvote. It's exactly the reverse: you get punished with -1s to your own reputation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Did I ever ask to get a veto on what is right or wrong? Doesn't "if it was flagged several times" seem to be a bit conflicting with that? The point is, as "downvote" and "close vote" are completely different types of votes, "wrong vote" should be different too. It's not on the "helpful" scale.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph your remarks about how downvotes don’t help when a post score goes from 6 to 5 suggest, strongly, that you want something more powerful, it speaks of impatience and a distrust of the voting system. We don’t need a ‘wrong answer’ flag, because voting already handles this. You just have to understand that it can take time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If 9 years of time is an insufficient scale of time to downvote 40 wrong answers, it doesn't really speak of impatience and subjective distrust in voting system, it speaks the voting system is objectively broken.

Comment: If you discourage users from downvoting others to tune anyone with positive vibes or whatever other reason, the website gets filled with really bad, wrong answers. Incidentally, those wrong answers get upvoted, because there is no visual sign to mark them as wrong, no way for novice users to deem them wrong, no nothing. Over years some of them get _highly_ upvoted, primarily for their sheer age. It doesn't get any better, the more time we try to understand it takes time, _the worse_ it gets.

Comment: It would make no more sense to downvote spam answers, because, you know, over time they will get enough downvotes to be dimmed and grayed out. "Wrong" and "helpful" are not on the same scale.

Comment: "*I don't understand how I failed to communicate the problem in the description above*" => Your Qt (Question) is not self-contained, one needs to follow 3 "vague" Links all 3 called "here", (that feel a bit like "Clickbait", no Tag mentioned), of which 2 link to some Qt (maybe 2 Qt's), and based on that you want to "revolutionize" the Voting and Flagging System. Hum..., OK, good luck I would say..., I don't see the "Urgency" for just 1 or 2 Qt's, let the Voting System decide and use your Downvotes and/or post a Comment to the "wrong" Answers, ... or post a "better" Answer yourself... :idea:

Answer (score 6):

There are flaws with each of these approaches.

1. Flags go to Moderators and Moderators are not subject matter experts in every possible tag. How could they determine that an answer was wrong when they aren't familiar with the technology?
2. The trouble with this is pretty much the same, you need to be a subject matter expert otherwise all you can do in the queue is skip, skip, skip. Maybe if you needed to be a gold badge holder in one of the question's tags but then there are plenty of tags with no gold badge holders at all. The queue would eventually fill up with answers that insufficient people are experts on.
3. Same as 1, who validates the flag? And if there's no queue, how do you know an answer has flags? This seems rather like delete votes on answers and we already have those. You and others in your tag just need 20K reputation and also be willing to use your delete votes.
4. There is an [outdated answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415738/outdated-answers-up-next-changes-to-sorting-menu) already so perhaps this addresses this point. Outdated answers are not necessarily useless though, many people end up working with obsolete technologies.

Let's contrast the concept of a wrong answer with what you need to know to vote to close.

- I don't know what it's asking but there sure are a lot of separate questions - OK I can vote to close as needing more focus.
- It's asking about the number of calories in a banana - I know that's not programming and so does almost everyone else here.
- It's in some other language than English - I don't have to understand that language at all to be able to vote to close.

I.e. I probably don't need to be a subject matter expert in the questions tags/technology to know there's a problem.

##### So what should we do about wrong answers?

Downvote them.

If an answer is highly upvoted and wrong then it's just possible your assessment of it isn't right. Downvoting isn't destructive, you can still see the answer and try it if you like, it just tells you that trying a different answer first may be a better idea.

Comment: 1. The proposed solution didn't ask for moderation attention, it specifically tells to put it into review queues, or to collect votes. Particularly, it asked to put "not an answer" handling from moderators to reviewers, because, as you said, moderators are not subject matter experts.

Comment: 2. The good mechanics are already figured out in close votes: several votes, matching reasons, review queue, gold badge to close singledhandledly.

Comment: 3. This is like delete votes, except we don't really want to delete outdated and wrong answers, either because they're still salvageable, or hold historic value.

Comment: 4. I don't know what to comment, other than I'm aware that it exists. I've never seen a discussion there to handle the other offenders: wrong and not-an-answers.

Comment: 2. If the flag provides a description of why the answer is wrong/not-an-answer, it shouldn't require much expertise. In mentioned examples, there is a case when an answer by industry leader recommend a drag and drop library for a question asking for a way to drag something around, where two things only happen to use the word "drag" for completely different concepts, and another case when the lag can be observed just by running provided code snippet. Neither requires profound knowledge of frontend development to reproduce.

Comment: Regarding the edit: do you need to be a subject expert matter to verify if provided code snippet is a cpu hog? SO is already a place where users are somewhat subject experts: they're programmers. For example, here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26453440/1872046) it was easy to communicate to at least 8 people this is not a proper answer to the question. In case the wrongness is so intricate that queue jury actually lack expert knowledge to support or deny it, probably it's just not such a big issue, and certainly not the majority of cases when the answer is blatantly wrong.