# How should I deal with an incorrect answer that is accepted and has massive upvotes?

Tags: feature-request, upvotes, wrong-answers

I'm looking at the question [How can I do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-can-i-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql) that has an accepted answer that is incorrect and that has been upvoted 832 times, at least.

I did my work: I downvoted it and added a comment. The downvote doesn't really make any difference, and the comment is just buried below a ton of other ones. No one will read it.

I was thinking maybe it could be flagged as incorrect. That way a warning sign could show up for naive users, the same way that Wikipedia does for poorly written articles.

So, the problem still stands. What would be the best way of dealing with a wrong answer like this one?

Comment: to begin with, cast a downvote, leave a comment, as you've done. Past that, all you can do is speak to other people (through chat, or a meta post like this one) to see if there's any consensus to have anything else done about it.

Comment: Also recently posted: [Flags for wrong and highly upvoted answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419910/2821954)

Comment: This question was closed and won't accept answers anymore. TLDR: according to the referenced question, the current solution (as of 8 years ago) is not to address this issue. I think I'll try ediring the answer myself to add the warning.

Comment: Given how many complaints we see about *downvotes*, how many complaints do you think we would see if we allowed a single, arbitrary user to flag an answer as "incorrect", placing a big warning sign/banner on it?

Comment: @CodyGray I agree. Was wondering if it could require more than a single one. Maybe something like the "closing" logic, that requires multiple people to agree with it. Thanks.

Comment: Only 800? How about 6500? [What is the difference between “INNER JOIN” and “OUTER JOIN”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578/3404097)

Comment: So you think that, perhaps, we could implement a voting system for answers, where users could click a button in the UI to indicate that the answer is incorrect? Hmm, I think we're back where we started.

Comment: IMO this is simply a... workflow? For lack of a better word. That follows around particular tags, SQL being one of them. People look for quick fixes rather than quality solutions. That comes with a frame of mind that triggers hasty decision making. Copy, paste, edit table and column names, I get data! -> upvote. Probably somewhere in the next week it'll come to light that the data was not exactly as desired. But by then it is already too late.