# Is the Outdated Answers project defunct now?

Tags: discussion, outdated-answer

Stack Overflow introduced the [Outdated Answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project) project two years ago and for [7-12 months made regular changes and updates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/answer-quality+product-discovery). But it has now been 13 months since [the last update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415738/outdated-answers-up-next-changes-to-sorting-menu) (that I could find using combinations of the [answer-quality](/questions/tagged/answer-quality), [product-discovery](/questions/tagged/product-discovery), and [announcement](/questions/tagged/announcement) tags).

The last update said (emphasis mine):

> We are still in the early stages of defining what features are must-have for a Minimum Viable Product and how we might build the functionality out over time. Stay tuned — we'll post in more detail and ask for lots of input in **the near future**.

What is the status of this project, are folks happy with sorting by Trending and we should expect other SE sites to soon have the option of using Trending sort? Or has development on this project ceased, with SO being the only site that will ever get access to the Trending feature?

Answer (score 12):

A-ha! There has in fact been [a more recent update by Kyle Pollard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418767/trending-a-new-answer-sorting-option) but it doesn't use any of the tags you've been searching for. (Gist: the feature was released June 21st **2022**, no current plans to expand to other SE sites.)

Perhaps when looking for future updates, try checking [Kyle's profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3023052/kyle-pollard), Anita Taylor has [moved on from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project#comment904660_405302). Or you could try browsing the [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) tag and hunt for posts submitted by someone with a Staff or Mod badge or with a high score?

Comment: [Anita Taylor left two years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project#comment904660_405302).

Comment: Mods don't have any involvement in the project. You're looking for the staff badge

Comment: june 21st a year ago, that trending feature has been active for a while, i'm not sure whether or not it's done anything useful.

Comment: Yeah, as KevinB said, that date is June 21st, _2022_; the trending sort feature is live on the main site and accessible from the sort dropdown above the first answer on the page. I actually really like the feature; I feel like it makes a big difference for JS questions where the language has gotten a lot of feature updates in the last decade. From my experience, it generally does a good job of letting more recent, useful answers drift upward quicker than the vote sort allows.

Comment: Can all the posts that relate to this project be tagged as [outdated-answers]? In some cases if the 5 tags limit is reached then [answers] can be replaced...