# Should I edit an obsolete (and incorrect) answer?

Tags: support

I came across this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9664327/688958

In short, it states that `text/javascript` is obsolete and that `application/javascript` should be used instead.

The answer was correct when [RFC 4329](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329) was current. However, in May 2022 that RFC was made obsolete by [RFC 9239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9239).

The new RFC states that `application/javascript` is obsolete and that `text/javascript` shall be used instead.

There's indeed [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74969699/688958) in that question that mention this fact.

However, the incorrect (and accepted) answer has a very high score (364). I believe that most people just assume that it has to be the correct answer. I would do so.

Now, it turns out I have enough reputation on Stack Overflow to edit other peoples' answers. Should I edit the answer and mention the new RFC or would that go against the philosophy/guidelines of Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'm not an SME, so I'm intentionally not posting an answer, however, in an area I was an SME in, I would edit the answer to denote when and what it was correct for, and then link to the answer that denotes the current correct solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle historical, highly upvoted but completely incorrect answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think there's a distinction there between answers that used to be correct but don't conform to the new standard, and answers that were never correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given:

1. [Outdated Accepted Answers: flagging exercise has begun](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407613/outdated-accepted-answers-flagging-exercise-has-begun) has (to my knowledge) not had a follow-up, so we can't add a banner like

   > "**Warning**: outdated, see [other answer] for the current value"
2. [How to handle historical, highly upvoted but completely incorrect answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers) was about answers that were wrong from the start, which this wasn't, it's just become outdated over time,
3. The [new sort order](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415738/outdated-answers-up-next-changes-to-sorting-menu) did not become a default and the correct answer won't flow up soon,
4. It will (figuratively) take ages for the [fourth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73542396/) (sitting at a score of 4 after 8 months), mentioning the renewed approach, to outrank the accepted answer at a score of 364,
5. [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) (the answerer) is very active and will receive a notification of an edit, and
6. It is a factual change for which you can provide a reference,

I'd say: just edit it.

People claim "don't change the meaning of the answer" as a reason not to update answers with changes over time (as newer versions of standards, languages and libraries emerge).

The question here, if we read past the phrasing that some people would call opinion-based *"Which [content-type] is best and why?"* and interpret it at face value, is:

> Which content-type should I use for JavaScript files?

The answer can be interpreted as such:

> According to the current standards, it is [...]

By taking this approach to editing, we can update answers without changing their meaning, but instead keeping them up-to-date. See also the Help Center's page  [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

> Editing is important for keeping posts clear, relevant, and up-to-date

and

> Some common reasons to edit a post are: [...] To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages

Comment: If Quentin is so active, it should be possible to simply ping them in a comment about their answer so they can edit their own answer... Much better than changing their answer to say something they didn't.

Comment: And place the burden upon them to incorporate the changes into the answer? I have a couple thousand answers out there, I applaud an edit changing outdated info instead of "hey you're outdated, go update". Rollback takes all of three clicks, you know.

Comment: It's their answer, they're getting rep for it, why shouldn't they bear the burden of keeping it up to date?

Comment: Are we here for the reputation or for building a knowledge base? Outdated knowledge serves nobody but historians, and they can view the edit history. It is all about momentum. As soon as someone determines an answer to be outdated and knows the up-to-date information, they can click edit and update the answer with very little effort. Posting a comment notifying the original poster, waiting, checking the answer again and again from your comments (if it isn't removed) and following up with an edit (days? weeks?) later when it appears to be ignored is very counterproductive.

Comment: What's the hurry? The answer has been wrong for almost a year. Serving JavaScript with `application/javascript` won't cause any browser to reject it, so at worst the response is not strictly following an RFC if it follows the advice in this answer.

Comment: This feels like a novel "legal theory", but it is a breath of fresh air for me.

Comment: Yea i mean, why should we care at all if an SO Q&A pair has been spreading misinformation for years, it's not our problem, /s

Comment: Quentin has edited the answer now so I can return to being lazy :-)

Answer (score 8):

> If Quentin is so active, it should be possible to simply ping them in a comment about their answer so they can edit their own answer... Much better than changing their answer to say something they didn't. –

Yes. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424385/should-i-edit-an-obsolete-and-incorrect-answer#comment955462_424387).

Sticking an obsolete notice at the top and locking it seems more than a little excessive!

Comment: I've unlocked it so you can edit

Comment: But do you agree to others editing your answer, if the changes can be backed up by an updated RFC or other authoritive reference?

Comment: Ah, you're here Quentin! Thanks for fixing it!

Answer (score 4):

So, there's a lesser-used path here, but I'm generally loathe to use it without some serious consideration: an obsolete lock. However, I think it's warranted here.

The options for fixing this with edits are

1. Edit in a notice that it's wrong and your answer is in another castle
2. Edit the right answer in

I really dislike #2 because it cuts the new correct answer out of the loop. Worse is you'll get people who don't notice the edit and flag the correct answer as a late retread of the older one. It's easy to miss and sometimes we'll remove the correct answer in error. That's a mess.

Edit notices are more palatable but now you wind up with the wrong answer still at the top, where people will downvote it (because it's no longer useful). Thus the lock can help preserve its former usefulness, while still acting as a guidepost. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9654420/2370483) is a good example of where the obsolete still exists, but without harming the former usefulness.

The other piece of the puzzle that pushed me towards an obsolete lock here is that **the language itself changed**. They were actively telling folks exactly what Quentin said, until they didn't. Quentin shouldn't be penalized for that, which is what apparently has been happening. An obsolete lock prevents his answer from taking any further beating.

I should note that I am not opposed to other solutions or suggestions (i.e. make an argument in comments that we don't need the obsolete lock). But I do not feel downvoting a previously good answer into oblivion serves anyone in this case.

Comment: Why do you want to lock an answer that as of a couple of months ago was correct, gained 350+ upvotes because of that, but is now incorrect, as opposed to letting people edit it? Languages, standards and frameworks get new functionality all the time.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of editing the answer to include an updated part, I'd just as a notice at the top stating that the answer is outdated, then link to the most complete updated answer. If an updated answer already exists, then there's no reason to repeat it in the old answer, just add a link. Perhaps some notice like this in a block quote to add attention:

> UPDATE YYYY-MM-DD: This answer was accurate when it was first written, however it is now outdated. Please refer to [OtherUser's answer](link to answer) for a more recent answer.

I think in a perfect world this would be a moderator notice to draw more attention and ensure trusted people are making these notices, however in the mean time it's a good solution.

Comment: I do actually like this approach the best, albeit with a less in your face "*UPDATE*" notice; something like "_In versions x to x, it worked like this..._". It 1) keeps the author's intent 2) keeps the old answer present for future readers who would benefit (though that's not very meaningful in this case) 3) indicates that the given answer is not current while avoiding cluttering up the answer with loud meta headings. If the author is around to update it, then by all means that should occur, but otherwise this seems like a happy medium _in cases where old answers are still relevant_.

Comment: _"If an updated answer already exists, then there's no reason to repeat it in the old answe"_ - except when the outdated answer outscores the updated one by 100 (50 now), is accepted and is above the fold for everyone. As a searcher/reader you should not have to doubt the top answer.

Comment: I'd like to note that despite this answer being at -1, it seems that it was effectively implemented by a mod [in this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9664327/7) (at least until the author updated his answer).