# Should we highlight old questions & answers?

Tags: discussion, old-questions, old-answers, outdated-answer

Sometimes you try to solve a problem by following an answer but it just won't work, while it seems to work for everyone else, (for example here on this [MySQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)) until you realise that the answer is old and the MySQL version is way behind your version.

Should we somehow highlight it more that it is an old question?

I know for some Q&A the date does not matter, but it would be still helpful to have a hint that you are looking at an old question. I don't know about you, but checking the date is usually not the first thing I do.

Comment: Relevant: [Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302)

Comment: I must admit, the example you give isn't example a "very old" question; it's from 2017.

Comment: @Larnu, you are correct, I edited my question.

Comment: "*checking the date is usually not the first thing I do.*" well you might not...but you have to. That's not to say that we shouldn't provide more information. I'm saying this because there is information *all over* the Internet which is rapidly getting outdated. Everything you might find is at risk at being old and obsolete - not just on SO, other sites, blogs, publications. I tend to immediately mistrust pages that don't have any indication how old they are. I don't even have a hint at whether the information is current and relevant.

Comment: On one hand, there's a point for this discussion since the date is shown on the bottom, thus for long answer, it might be too late to notice the date after reading it. On the other hand, might want to test "newest post" sorting option (hidden option:`?answertab=createddesc`).

Comment: Just because a *question* is old doesn't mean (some of) the answers are either. Some questions are constantly having new answers added as new features come to the technology the question is about, and thus easier or built-in methods exist to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Larnu, I never proposed to delete them. The old ones should get highlighted somehow

Comment: @AndrewT., sorting by score is more important to me than sorting by date.

Comment: @VLAZ, I know that the first thing everyone should do is look at the date, but I bet in reality almost no one does it

Comment: When did I mention deletion, @Black ?

Comment: @Larnu, never, but you seem to understand my proposal wrong. New answers / comments should not be highlighted, so your objection is pointless anyways.

Comment: @Black I'm saying this from experience: they *should*. Because I was also ignoring the dates and I've spent countless hours trying out solutions from 2005 and wondering why they don't work when it's 3-4 versions behind.

Comment: So what *are* you asking if not *"Should we somehow highlight it more that it is an old question?"* As I stated, just because the question is old doesn't mean the answer(s) are.

Comment: @Larnu, Just highlight the old question and old answers (+ comments if you like) as old and let new answers/comments stay unchanged.

Comment: Highlight how? What is the logic behind what denotes that it needs highlighting, when (as already mentioned) the date the post was created and last updated are already there? Is a question that is "old" (by your terms a few years old) has a recent answer, does it not get highlighted? What about an answer that is 10 years old but editted yesterday? What does this highlighting tell the reader that the creation/edit date doesn't already tell them?

Comment: By highlighting I mean (JUST FOR EXAMPLE!) add a special border around it or an icon, something that pops into your eye and is not at the very bottom of the question / answer and gets overlooked.

Comment: Why is the use of an older version of MySQL relevant? Outside of a missing feature, Solutions to older versions, should remain relevant to newer versions. Standards don’t typically break solutions with newer versions being released. Perhaps only exceptions might be with respect to truly broken solutions related to encryption. Why focus on the fact it’s older? The date already is provided.

Comment: "*Just highlight the question and old answers*" then what *is* old? I guarantee you that PrototypeJS has not changed since 2017. The last release is from 2015. So any questions you find from 2017 would most likely be up-to-date and current. Unless they ask for an older release.

Comment: That doesn't tell me what this highlighting is meant to inform the reader of, or *when* it is supposed to appear.

Comment: It was obviously just an example. Of course you could also add a text or something better.

Comment: And what would that text say? *When* does that text appear?

Comment: @Larnu, obviously something like "Be aware that this question/answer is X years old and might be outdated." or even better a link where you explain it further in an article.

Comment: @VLAZ, "then what is old?"
 the community could vote if something is outdated and if the vote was successfull, then the "highlighting" should appear.

Comment: Does the highlighting happen automatically? If yes, by what criteria. Or manually, e.g. a queue, or something new similar to the lock/protected action?

Comment: @Lino, In my oppinion the community should vote if a question/answer is outdated.

Comment: Right, so what you are proposing is the Outdated Answers project.

Comment: So questions that are X years old (what is *X*? 2 years? 5 years? 10 years?) needs to be linked to an article about what? The subject matter? How does [so] automagically determine what that subject matter is? If a question, even from 12 years ago, is still correct for the latest and greatest version of the technology, should the message stikll appear? Again, how does [so] determine that automagically?

Comment: @Larnu What exactly did you not understand about voting? X should be obviously the amount of years the answer or question is old, it should be inserted dynamically.

Comment: @Black you have *only just mentioned* voting, which was in a comment posted literally a minute or so before my last comment, and submitted while I was typing said comment; with the greatest of respect, I *can't* read your mind nor can I predict what your future comments are going to say while I type my own...

Comment: *"X should be obviously the amount of years the answer or question is old, it should be inserted dynamically"* So there should be a message above an answer posted yesterday stating *""Be aware that this question/answer is 0 years old and might be outdated."*? You've still not stated *when* this message should start appearing.

Comment: @Larnu I start to believe you are just trolling, you can't be serious with your questions. Why should someone be able to vote for a 0 year old question to be old? Are you serious?

Comment: The problem is your proposal lacks any information on what you *actually want to happen*. You sprong voting on me in the comments and asked if I had "never heard of it", yet your question make *no mention* of voting. Of course, I, and others, are going to ask you to elaborate because all your post says is that you want to "highlight" the posts, that are "old" (with no definition of what "old" is), and you give *one* example of a question from 5 years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than highlight old content "newbies" should spend time learning how Stack Overflow works and about [digital literacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_literacy).

---

Stack Overflow isn't really too old, it was launched in 2009 while the web was opened to the public in 1991<sup>1</sup> and several technologies are older than that, i.e. SQL first appeared in 1974<sup>2</sup>.

Stack Overflow posts have a creation and modification date and the search engine has operators so if the user is looking for content about the latest version they could search for posts created and/or modified after the release date of that version.

As was already mentioned in the comments there is an active initiative to better handle obsolete content [Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302/1595451). Also SO has [bounties](/questions/tagged/bounties) to get attention to questions, one of the canned reasons is to request for up-to-date information:

> **Current answers are outdated**
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

On most posts anyone can suggest an edit. This feature could be used to remark that an answer doesn't work on a newer release.

People with rep > 50 could comment, i.e. to say that the answer doesn't work in certain circumstances like using the latest release or due to changes to required stuff like drivers, operative system, certificates, etc.

[tags](/questions/tagged/tags) could be used to identify questions about a specific version or "flavor". [tag-wikis](/questions/tagged/tag-wikis) could be used to provide guidance about how to find and/or tag questions, and warn users about dated / obsolete sources, i.e. when certain technology was abandoned by the original developers and relaunched in some way could be suggested to use the documentation of the current developers / maintainers rather than the original reference docs.

Notes:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Comment: While I agree personally about 'oldness', Stack Overflow _is_ quite old for a lot of people. It won't be long until many of its users were not even born by the time it was around... a couple of years, maybe. Especially considering the rate at which websites and web technologies change/progress, 14 years is _ancient_ ...(Internet Explorer **7** was the latest/greatest web browser when SO launched).