# Duplicate question, but years apart

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

What is the correct way to deal with a duplicating an old question?

Given a question "How do I do xxxxx in JavaScript?" with a question and accepted answer from say 2013, how do I ask the same question in 2023, given that, although the question will be the same, the answer will be different due to changes in JavaScript over the last decade?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project)

Comment: What makes you so confident that the answer would be *completely* different?  JavaScript has improved, but it's still backwards compatible for most things.

Comment: Maybe related/dupe: [What should I do if a question has been asked and answered, but software (and answer) has changed?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400380)

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate. Thats ironic

Comment: @Tom many thanks - looking at that thread, it seems there is no consensus. I'll close this Q as a dupe of the the one you linked

Comment: Ask how to do it in ES6 or a future spec specifically, I would say. There is not just "Javascript" (or ecmascript), it is split up into different specification versions each introducing new features. A good example that I make use of myself a lot is the Map and Set. No more abusing arrays as primitive hash tables for me.

Answer (score 11):

If the old question does not specify a particular version of the language that it applies to, then you should assume that the question can apply to all versions. If a new version of a language comes out that allows for a better approach than what's in the existing answers, then an answer showing the new approach should be posted on the old canonical question. The question shouldn't be posted again.

If you wish for an up-to-date answer on a canonical question that currently lacks one, [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to the question with the notice of:

> **Current answers are outdated**
>
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.